# Can we have a way to see a user's activity page by default?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

The title says it all: If I click on a user name, I do not want to land on the new profile page, but on the activity page. The motivation for that can be explained with a quote from [the announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/?cb=1):

> The Profile Page lets you show others a summary of what you’re all about. Share your interests, favorite charities, or your Twitter, Github, and SO Careers activity. Or don’t. And it automatically shows off your most helpful posts and tags from the network.

If I visit another user's profile, I'm usually not interested in any of this. I mostly want to get a quick overview of their recent activity, their overall distribution of contributions, and often look for specific actions, e.g., recent edit suggestions, in order to look for spam or invalid mass retaggings. The assumption expressed in the announcement that the activity page is *"full of stuff that you may care about, but others probably didn’t"* is simply wrong when you take moderation into account.

I can still see all of this on the activity page, but getting there now costs me an extra click. I'd love to have a way of landing there by default. I can think of two ways to implement this:

- Remember which page I visited last. This is already done for, e.g., the filters of the "all actions" subtab of the activity page and seems like it should be a simple change. A possible downside: it can potentially confuse people who are unaware of the behaviour.
- Provide an explicit setting. This removes the potential for confusion, but it has the downside that people might not find it. Also, there is currently no category in the preferences where it feels like such a setting would belong.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm sure it would be fairly trivial to make a Greasemonkey userscript. Anyone ?

Comment: @JonasCz I guess it would be simple, but a userscript solution would be suboptimal as one would have to install the script in all used browsers, potentially over multiple PCs. It might also be undesirable or disallowed to install browser addons or userscripts in some situations, e.g. in a workplace environment.