# Don’t show “top posts” with negative score

Tags: discussion, profile-page

To new users, the new profile page seems a bit mean when it shows the list of “top posts“ where the only entry is a question with a negative score:

[image: Top post with negative score]

Of course, we want new users to understand how Stack Overflow works and prevent them from posting such bad questions. But having the profile page list those under the big header “top posts“ seems quite mean.

I think it would make more sense to just hide posts with negative score altogether from that list. Those shouldn’t be part of the “top posts”.

(Btw. I’m not asking to completely hide negative posts; they would be still visible from the activity tab with all the other stuff. I just would prefer them not being shown as a “top post”.)

Comment: but...we *are* quite mean...no?

Comment: If we decide to hide, **DON'T** hide it when you're looking at your own profile. That user has a right to be reminded every time that they need to improve.

Comment: Related (on Meta Stack Exchange): [Should we be highlighting downvoted posts in “top posts”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254063/should-we-be-highlighting-downvoted-posts-in-top-posts)

Comment: @rene That’s a good point, although I think we could do that in an even more prominent place instead too (Like somewhere at the top, in a dedicated area, so that we can educate new users properly).

Comment: Would it make it harder to spot if a user is vandalising their downvoted posts?

Comment: @RobertLongson If you take an average user, they would probably have multiple questions, so you would see the actual top posts there. The ones most-downvoted would be hidden by the overflow already. And the activity tab will show all questions anyway. So if you want to take a look at the “worst” posts of a user, you would have to look there anyway.

Comment: This post seems to assume that all new users are going to have negative scoring posts, and that's a false premise.

Comment: Apart from that, and maybe I'm being really mean here, I don't see anything bad about showing negative scoring posts in the "top posts" **if** those are the only posts that the user has. Everybody is special in their own way and we all have been new to SO at one point, but this is a "site for professional and enthusiast programmers" and not a daycare. We all are (or should be) adults and know that if we do something wrong there are consequences (and in this case a really _soft_ one). Also, it's not like the user doesn't have options to prevent this situation (he/she could delete the question)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro spot on, please consider submitting your comments as an answer...

Comment: Question: Do we think that users with nothing but low-quality posts give a flying *duck about their profile page? If the answer is no, then why the hand-wringing? Whom are we trying to do favours to?

Comment: As Alvaro said, “we all have been new to SO at one point”, so shouldn’t we try to encourage users to *improve* the quality of their posts?

Comment: @RobertLongson _Would it make it harder to spot if a user is vandalising their downvoted posts?_ - The new profile page already makes everything related to moderation harder. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290367/can-we-have-a-way-to-see-a-users-activity-page-by-default for a related feature request.

Comment: "The floggings will continue until morale improves..."

Comment: Is this a perceived problem, or do we have users actively complaining about how their profile looks because of their poorly-received questsions?

Answer (score 50):

If "Top Posts" is intended to show a user's highest-voted posts, then so be it even if the highest-voted posts are negative. As a SO user who deliberately clicks on a user's profile page to see who he is, I do **not want to be misled** by hiding the user's previous behaviour.

If the user in question cares about his profile page, and his appearance in the SO community, then he can ask better questions and provide some good answers. I'll not think badly of a user who's top post is at -2, if his top answer is at +10 or even +1. Additionally, in the extremely unlikely situation that the user is a veteran user (i.e. many questions and answers) and his top posts *still* are negative, then **I need to know that when I view his profile page**.

Comment: It is not easy to ask better questions, just for the sake of it. I have asked one question and would like to ask more, but honestly, I don't have to, most of my questions are already answered and I spend my time searching for answers.

Comment: @martin: I address your concern with mention of _good answers_. A user with only negative-scoring questions but positive-scoring answers is fine. In fact, I recently asked what was in my opinion a well-researched question that addresses a basic concept, it was downvoted and removed. There is nothing wrong with a downvoted question or two.

Comment: yes, I read that after I commented (wrong order, I know), but I read that particular argument quite often, so I decided to throw my 2 cents in.

Answer (score 21):

Maybe I'm being really mean here, I don't see anything bad about showing negative scoring posts in the "top posts" **if** those are the only posts that the user has.

Everybody is special in their own way and we all have been new to SO at one point, but this is a "site for professional and enthusiast programmers" and not a daycare. We all are (or should be) adults and know that if we do something wrong there are consequences (and in this case a really *soft* one).

Also, it's not like the user doesn't have options to prevent this situation (they could delete the question if they didn't want it to be displayed on their profile.)

Comment: ["Everyone's a hero in their own way. In their own not-that-heroic way."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Horrible%27s_Sing-Along_Blog)

Comment: "they could delete the question" -- Except when they can't. One upvoted answer is enough to block deletion of the question.

Comment: @hvd however, they could still disassociate it from their account. would making it a community wiki also have the same effect?

Comment: @KevinB They can't, but sure, they can ask a mod to do it for them.