# The default tab when you click your profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Can we have an option to pick your tab when clicking our name? I'm asking because I have an active link with all my tags in my profile and it's annoying changing all the time from activity to profile tab.

Comment: I am constantly doing the opposite for other users, where I click past their profile to their activity. It would be nice if it just remembered what tab you were on last regardless of the profile and just used that.

Comment: Yes, the system manages to remember which tab I last used for questions (which I'd prefer it didn't, but I guess any default stands a good chance of not being the one I want, active) and doesn't remember for profile (which I'd prefer it to do).

Comment: For your specific case, I recommend bookmarking that link in your browser so you don't have to go to your profile every time.

Comment: FYI your link is broken, "+c+or+c++" translates as "or [c] or [c]".

Comment: Related: [Can we have a way to see a users activity page by default?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290367/can-we-have-a-way-to-see-a-users-activity-page-by-default)

Comment: Can we just go back to the old profiles which were actually functional and not the crap we have now ?