# Why is being honest getting penalized these days?

Tags: discussion

It is beyond any doubt that the poster of this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893192/what-is-c-program-code-for-call-void-function-with-parameter

is not competent to write C programs, (yet).  Despite being a member of SO for 1 year, 3 months, s/he does not understand parameters/arguments and so cannot handle the clear and unambiguous (for a change) compiler error messages.

So, obviously not a professional or enthusiast, and so is misusing SO as a fixer for very basic errors that the most tardy of enthusiasts would have sorted out after a week of learning, never mind 15 months.

Is it really so unconstructive, offensive or hostile to point this out?

I ask because my comment to that effect got deleted, and deleted comments tend to lead to account suspensions.  Last time I moaned about 'i++ + ++i'-style UB questions, (ie. multi-duped garbage/trash from profs/TAs and copypasta straight to SO), I got suspended for 30 days.

What is the recommended approach to such questions these days?  'Economy with the truth'?  Pointless platitudes in an attempt to increase SO membership/revenue at the expense of Q&A quality?  Ignore so that they can ask another question when they reach the next page of K&R?

It's all too easy for posters to take criticism of their hopeless questions as a personal affront and flag such comments as unconstructive/offensive, and SO mods swallow this, seemingly without question, no matter how bad the question.

NOTE: the question pointed at by link above has now been deleted, so 10K+ only:(

Edit:  It has been brought to my attention that the word 'tardy' can have a different meaning than 'late' or 'delayed' and, indeed, can be interpreted as a rude, personal insult.

That was not intended, and should the OP of my linked question be reading this, I'm sorry for the lack of knowledge that led me to use a word that could be misinterpreted and I sincerely apologize for any offense caused.  You can be assured that I will not use it again in SO comments.

Also, those who berate me for so-called 'excessive hostility and/or rudeness', may like to handle this user before I do:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942579/pseudocode-that-prints-numbers-between-100

Comment: What was the comment you left? There's pointing out, and then there's pointing out.

Comment: Is it a case of "it's not **what** you said but **how** you said it"?

Comment: I'm guilty of making such comments from time to time as well. Push comes to shove, we're turning a simple flag or downvote into a verbal outing that is only for our own benefit in the end - and its a pointless attempt because people who you try to educate are not in the mindset to be educated. when they already make their life a living hell by refusing to study and learn to understand anything, they won't accept a deeper understanding from you either.

Comment: @Bart - I don't know exactly - it's been deleted:)    I have no problem with any mod reproducing it here in full or partially - it was not personally offensive IMHO.

Comment: Okay @MartinJames, just asking. I have in the past pointed out something similar, which got a decent amount of flack in a Meta discussion. So I know it can be tricky even when you try to say so with the best of intentions. I wouldn't at all be surprised if such a comment fell victim to user flags.

Comment: Your heart is in the right place but by the time its sentiments reaches your lips, the message tends to acquire a lot of snark.  You'll have to get used to the fact that the investors in SE have these kind of people as their untrained low-wage staff and expect SO users to help them get their job done for free.  SE community leads will never do anything to make it easy to delete content like this is a constructive way.  You can vote, you can pick close reasons and it really doesn't matter to anybody here that it contains weasel words and does not match what you want to say.  All you can do

Comment: The problem is that a *lot* of people simply mistake honesty for hostility. That's always going to be the case, no matter how matter-of-fact-objective the criticism is.

Comment: *"So, obviously not a professional or enthusiast,"* - I don't know crap about C, but I do think I'm a professional and and enthusiast.

Comment: @GolezTrol - can you match up parameters and arguments in your language of choice?

Comment: It is just the way of the world. While some will have no problem when you say _Dude, pick up a C book and save us and yourself of all the trouble_  and will thank you for advice, others will tell you to _Go and mind your own business_ even when your comment is overly polite and full of _Please,..._

Comment: @J.Steen *"the truth hurts"* -- Humanity

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, but for *that* language I wouldn't ask that question, but I might if I enthousiastically started to explore C. Not saying that this particular question is great, but you cannot say someone is not enthusiast (or not professional even), if they seem incompetent about the subject of the question.

Comment: @GolezTrol That just sounds likes semantics...

Comment: Note that the language barrier can also affect how your words are percieved. You may think you're being firm but polite, but it may not be taken the same way by someone who doesn't have English as their first language.

Comment: there is a lot of history being glossed over here. I'm not at all sure you really want it to be publicized. It's a better idea to contact the community team directly than have this on meta.

Comment: Perhaps ultimately a duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I'm not afraid of history, whether good or bad.  It just is, I cannot rewrite it.  If you feel that you need to republish it, go ahead:)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker is there an applicable close reason for "I was already repeatedly and specifically warned about this, but I did it anyway?"

Comment: @apaul34208 Not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Just seems to come up on Meta often enough... The sort of "Why did this happen?" or "Why did the mods do X?" or "What am I supposed to do when X happens?" Then a moderator shows up with the "We already told you in private, do we really need to do this publicly?"

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Seems like we should be able to close these as veiled rants or something.

Comment: @apaul34208 Problem with a moderator closing it is then it looks like we're hiding something, when in reality we're just not the type to air someone's dirty laundry.  When they start airing their own dirty laundry, then we get involved so there isn't the appearance that we're being hamfisted. But over all, the fake "I have no idea why I was suspended / what I did was wrong" is pretty transparent for all involved, at least it should be.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Fair enough...

Comment: On a lighter note, take a look at this response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: One should provide feedback in constructive and polite way - and not in mean way

Comment: The main reason the vampires are still here is that they still get help. Who upvoted those four answers? People answering vampire questions like these get down votes from me.

Comment: "Is it really so unconstructive, offensive or hostile to point this out?" - Yes.  It's not germane to answering the question, and thus completely irrelevant.  Unhelpful, irrelevant content doesn't get points for being true.  Help, or help not.  There is no try.

Comment: Off-topic-ish, but what's up with the close reason: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"?

It's neither. 

That question simply shows a lack of basic understanding of how programming works, and I don't think this close reason fits.

Comment: @doubleDown The close reasons usually don't fit that occurs often

Comment: @doubleDown You are right, we need a close reason for questions that show a lack of effort or understanding of the used language/tool. Sometimes I would like to say: "Read the documentation, google it, learn some <language> and you'll see it's easy." I know that RTFM is not a good answer, but if feels sometimes appropriate.

Comment: How long someone has been a member of the site has no effect on how much they learn or how much time they spend here. Someone can join, then not visit the site at all for years. I joined years ago but wasn't really active until last year.

Comment: @doubleDown There used to be a close reason for "lacks basic understanding" (note that this means that the *question* fails to demonstrate basic understanding;  that could just be a communication failure by an OP who actually has basic understanding).  That close reason is no longer in use (which is unfortunate, in my opinion).

Comment: What does "UB" refer to?

Comment: @Air 'Undefined Behaviour' - like Meta on a Friday afternoon.

Comment: I'm totally simpatico with the distaste for questions from noobs who have not learned any basics. **However** we do ourselves a disservice when we express our dissatisfaction in any but the nicest of terms. I follow a simple rule that I have recently formulated to help me combat this: **"Don't type grumpy."** I could be wrong, but I think it might benefit more people than just myself.

Comment: I was 95% sure after reading the question title that I was going to downvote it.

Comment: *"may like to handle this user before I do"* ... that's a good sign for you just needing to step away from that one.

Comment: Sure, the user may be rude, but its no reason to stoop to his level and be so condescending.

Comment: @MartinJames Seeing as I wrote that Answer, and seeing as I still think it was the right thing to do, if OP wants to copy paste that into his homework, he should. He will loose out on the learning effect and fail later. I do think though that these types of questions do help later visitors, who will not be dumb enough to not read the explaination on top first and maybe learn something.

Comment: @Magisch lol, did you not notice the continual pleading from the OP 'give me the correct code'?   No matter who tried to help by dropping hints, or suggesting debug strategies, the OP's response was the same: 'give me the correct code'.  The OP was absolutely determined to get SO slaves to answer its homework question without striking a single blow itself.  It was an insulting, disrespectful con job, and you fell for the chutzpah:(

Comment: @MartinJames What? That must've been in the comments. I didn't read the comments. The question was pretty clear and straightforward to answer without them. I usually only read comments if I have trouble discerning what exactly OP wants. Only after the downvote and reading this here did I read them. If you notice, I also expanded my answer to include extensive explaination on why he is wrong after that. I guess I'm maybe thinking to highly of OP to assume he would actually care and read that.

Comment: @Magisch I thought that your C code example was very good - the OP was after pseudocode, and so you were pointing the way in a clear fashion,(a bit too clear for me, but whatever:).  What happened then?  'thanks but i asked for a pseudocode' - which you dutifully served up:(  You need to get better street-smarts else the vampires will bleed you dry:)

Comment: @MartinJames I usually don't concern myself with the Asker's motive, but instead with the solution and explaination of my answer. You also downvoted before I even added the pseudocode, so I thought it was mainly because I did the C and not the pseudo like OP asked.

Comment: @Magisch - never entered my head:)    It'll be some OP who I outed as a deadbeat and so did not get their entire homework done for them:)

Comment: @aroth I doubt that Haris and Arc676 think that karmic balance has been restored by upvoting an answer that was a slap in the face to their efforts to instruct the OP on how to debug/fix its own code:(  That's two contributors who will probably not bother to assist such posters in future and will just anonymously down/close vote instead:(

Comment: @MartinJames I'd delete my answer, but its not letting me, because the answer has been accepted.

Comment: Good grief, that pseudo-code question....I can't believe someone actually posted the pseudo-code, after all the help he got, and all that rude nagging for an answer that wouldn't require any thought at all.

Comment: lol, I got a, (somewhat unwanted), 'Notable Question' badge for all this.   Maybe there should be an 'Infamous Question' badge?

Comment: It IS possible to provide honest feedback that is also polite. Brutal honesty may have its place, but that place is not in a widely read public forum with complete strangers.

Comment: 15 months without learning anything, isn't that guy a real enthusiast?

Comment: Honesty ~= Hostility is why I have a signature on some forums that says, "Apparently I am a complete and utter asshole here to make your personal life miserable. If you feel this is the case **just report me** as pointing it out will only make me report you" or similar, as I seem to come across as some high-and-mighty twat when informing people that they're doing something wrong. The second clause is there because I've taken it upon myself to no longer get into pointless arguments over my bruskness. Human psychology being what it is, saying "No I'm not" only makes you seem even *more* hostile.

Comment: @miradulo EVERYTHING in writing is semantics

Answer (score 320, accepted):

Being honest and being polite aren't mutually exclusive goals. There are plenty of ways to provide constructive criticism about a question without demeaning someone's abilities or otherwise being rude to them.

We all recognize that the largest problem facing Stack Overflow is the large and growing volume of low quality content coming into the site. In the face of that, it's easy to get frustrated and take it out on people asking poorly written questions. You have to remember that there is a person on the other side of that glowing screen. I've said this many times before, but all people on this site deserve to be treated politely and with respect, even if you feel they have not earned it.

I know that it can feel cathartic to vent on someone posting the fifth "plz gv teh codez urgnt now" question of the day, but that doesn't really help anyone. If a passer-by looks at a poorly-asked post and sees people mocking the asker, in many cases that will simply make them think the people here are nasty and intolerant. I've seen this happen.

Use your downvotes and close votes on this content, but instead of making remarks about someone's ability level, either provide a polite comment explaining what's wrong with the post and how to fix it or move along.

For the particulars of this case, the comment that was removed was the following:

> 'Member for 1 year, 3 months' and you ask this? You are clearly not a professional or enthusiast programmer. You need to accumulate more knowlege and experience before posting here. ATM, you don't understand compiler error messages, even when they are explicit and clear, (and you are lucky that's the case - it's surely not always the case).

This was flagged by a community member as being rude, and removed for that reason. The first two sentences disparaged someone's skill level, and the remainder didn't really help to clarify the question. Generally, if a comment is considered rude by a moderator or a member of the community and it does not add value to a question or answer, we delete it when flagged.

You don't get automatically suspended as a result of getting any number of comments deleted, but we do step in when we feel there is a pattern of troubling behavior in comments. As you are willing to discuss the specifics of your case, moderators noticed a large number of your comments getting flagged for being rude to people (we deleted 150 of them in the span of a couple of months) and several of them were very inappropriate.

At that point, we provided a gentle warning that you might want to tone this down a bit. That did happen, but the comments started picking up again. You started leaving some rather harsh comments for people on Meta who were just coming here for help on asking better questions. Then you left [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299924/why-do-so-contributors-say-my-question-is-off-topic-when-its-not), which caused me to contact you and state that things were getting troubling.

Again, these comments tailed off for a bit, but then gradually resumed. More concerning, we started to see custom close vote reasons like this being used:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contains UB,
>   the words 'exploit', 'vulnerability' and because I feel like it.
>
> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP does not
>   sufficiently understand the grammar of the language.to generate a good
>   question.
>
> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's rubbish,
>   asking for nails to be hammered in but banning hammers and nails. This
>   is of next-to-no use to future visitors to SO.

and were getting flags about them. We provided another warning about this.

We finally suspended you from the site for a week after you continued to post close reasons like

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because trash code
>
> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because malicious
>   question.
>
> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because priority close.
>
> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a works
>   request
>
> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's
>   extra-urgent that this question be closed.
>
> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because exploit crap,
>   and I'm sick and tired of pandering to those that seek to waste my
>   time and money.

The close vote reasons continued like that after the suspension, thus the further 30-day suspension.

I know you care about the quality of the site and are frustrated with some of the trash that comes in here, but there are more constructive ways to deal with this. Again, downvote, pick a standard close vote, and move on.

You also have to separate the people who really don't care from those who might improve if given the chance. I have sympathy for the latter, which is why I react strongly when I see them coming to Meta for advice on asking better questions only to be mocked by people here. There are real people behind every question here, and I believe that all of them deserve to be treated with respect.

Comment: lol, it should be said however, in my defense, that the words/phrases like 'malicious', priority' and 'extra-urgent' were  taken from the OP's questions.  I will carry on down/close voting anything that smells of malware development.  It costs me money to keep malware off my systems, both in direct AV costs and the waste of machine resources required to run them, and so I will always DCV them, (though I will refrain from pointing out why in future:).

Comment: 'Trash code' was, of course, 'i++ + ++i' UB, code not only mega-duped prof/TA inventions copypasta,  but also just hopelessly bad and a terrible example to future users:(

Comment: You could make this answer constructive by expounding on "more constructive ways".  Which is his question afaik.  I'm curious as well.

Comment: There isn't much more that can be said than "downvote, pick a standard close vote, and move on". Since it's understandably difficult to channel one's frustration into constructive commentary, the next best alternative is to just not say anything at all.

Comment: For those <10k who can't see the question linked, my favorite part of it is "*I demand that my on-topic questions get the upvotes that they are entitled to!"* xD

Comment: OK, now that you've all fallen into my trap:) I can ask 'What close-reason would you have picked for this question', because I sat there for a couple of minutes looking at it, in stupified amazement, and was unable to think of one close-reason that matched.

Comment: @Martin it makes more sense that you took "priority", "extra-urgent" etc. from the questions themselves, which says a lot about those questions. However, I see how close vote reasons should be much more formal than occasionally rude comments. Eventually the question will be closed, and there's a chance that your custom message will be displayed on a banner. People might not read the crap question, but see the banner shouting rudeness/nonsense. That's clearly not the right thing to do. While I wouldn't bash you for being occasionally fed up in comments, I see why CV reasons are very different.

Comment: _"all people on this site deserve to be treated politely and with respect, even if you feel they have not earned it."_ Yeah this is the crux of it, really.

Comment: @BoltClock: I think for some of us there's an extremely strong temptation to go beyond deciding what's of value to the site, and try to add some value to the OP's life and the industry more generally by steering these OPs away from their current behaviours. To at least make them aware of how far behind they are, that we're not just saying their question is inappropriate for SO, but inappropriate for an actual person with a brain and a non-offensive amount of non-laziness. _(cont.)_

Comment: _(cont.)_ I think we genuinely want everyone to be better off, and perhaps hope that firmly indicating they're on the wrong track will make them think a little about how to get on the right track. Now, I'm not suggesting in any way that we _should_ be doing this, or that we should be rude while doing so. I'm just sort of thinking out loud about why this sort of thing happens. It's not always people just venting or lauding their skills over others, contrary to what I often hear proposed. _(cont.)_

Comment: _(cont.)_ Anyway, by that token, "pick a standard close vote and move on" would feel unsatisfying and ineffective to people with those "extended goals" Like not telling someone their fly is down. Perhaps this is why so many go further. Just some Thursday lunchtime thoughts. :)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Completely agreed. It can be a fine line, I think.

Comment: @MartinJames Not all questions that you should downvote should be closed. This is one such question.

Comment: "There are real people behind every question here, and I believe that all of them deserve to be treated with respect." Probably the #1 problem I have with a great many 10k+ users is that they don't keep this in mind.

Comment: Broadly agree that these are malicious trash close reasons justifying the user's priority removal from the site for a little while, but a couple are unobjectionable. *"I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's rubbish, asking for nails to be hammered in but banning hammers and nails. This is of next-to-no use to future visitors to SO."* is curt, but clear and helpful; *"I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a works request"* is unclear and unhelpful, but not rude. I don't think close reasons like those - even if used repeatedly - warrant a suspension.

Comment: @MartinJames Isn't "unclear what you're asking" still an option?

Comment: @TylerH - does someone who is bleeding SO contributors for complete homework answers and then selling them to other students worthy of respect?  I mean, other than respect for being able to run such a con on the skilled and experienced engineers on SO?

Comment: @MartinJames: "*does someone who is bleeding SO contributors for complete homework answers and then selling them to other students worthy of respect?*" I could ask the reverse: why should we respect someone who wants to be rude to people? *Both* groups of people are detrimental to the site, just in different ways. Being discourteous to the kind of people you describe is not a viable way to get rid of them. It **is** however a signal to any 3rd party reading the comments that they shouldn't post things here.

Comment: Well said, Brad!

Comment: @MartinJames Assuming you meant "is" rather than "does", yes, they deserve respect. You don't have to answer their question, and you can even tell them why, but you should still be respectful in doing so. If you aren't sure you can be respectful while telling someone you won't help them, then you probably shouldn't be engaging with them at all. There's no rule saying you have to talk to people or answer their questions here. There *is*, however, a rule that says you have to be nice.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i completely agree with you. I'll add that some user that get downvoted and closed for their [whatever make their post really low quality] post. They complain already that we're being rude in their post or meta. So if we want to add something, whatever the way you turn this, they'll complain even more. IMO the fact they came saying we're rude here is not necessary a good indicator of this. I even read some post from other meta stackexchange saying we're a rude community and not from newcomers. it's just SO need to be a bit more strict to keep i quality due to the volume.

Comment: @Walfrat: Yeah a lot of people equate "didn't give me my solution immediately, regardless of anything else" with "being rude". Some of it's fundamental misunderstanding of how SO works, some of it's fundamental misunderstanding of how the world works, and some of it's a feeling of entitlement. And that's even before we get to people being direct/firm! We can't really do anything about that. They're certainly entitled to _think_ people are being rude, just as we're certainly entitled to completely ignore that view.

Comment: I really want to open a chat with you Brad.

Comment: So... he got [_Larsoned_](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DndWh.png)? :)

Answer (score 88):

Being honest isn't a problem, being rude is. Stack Overflow has a [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy for a reason. Tone will greatly affect how someone responds to your words, and a harsh, negative or blunt tone will just come off as abrasive even if you're annoyed that someone seems to be flouting the rules and expecting free help with no effort.

You should give people the benefit of the doubt at all times, rather than assuming that you have an accurate impression of them. As much as you can feel certain of something, you don't know what someone's life is. Maybe they are trying really hard, but English is not their first language so the unambiguous compiler message is extra complicated for them, even aside from following the jargon that reads clearly to you.

Of course I'm not saying to disregard their erroneous use of SO or let them off the hook. I just think that if you start from the assumption that people are reasonable, and treat them as such, you'll get a better response even as you correct them on their mistakes.

Comment: Being slightly cynical, if there's one reason for that policy it's to attract eyeballs. Advertising income depends on quantity, not quality (as seen in the justification for the ad trackers - they're needed because advertisers want the raw visitor count). Martin James counts as one, just as much as the lazy person whose question is now deleted.

Comment: Yeah.. if only that was actually workable.  Being nice, and correcting umm.. 'mistakes' that look suspiciously like do-all-my-work-for-me, just spawns even more bad questions that need 'mistakes' correcting as the deadbeats realize just how naive SO contributors are in the face of a well-disguised homework dump:(   Soon, nothing gets done except correcting 'mistakes'.

Comment: Downvote and vote to close then - all such questions are usually covered by _existing policy_ options.

Comment: @MSalters That's certainly also a case but I think the Be Nice policy is also useful for this reason.

Comment: @MartinJames There are systems in place to deal with bad questions, I didn't say using them wasn't nice. I don't see how being nice and constructive while flagging, downvoting and close voting questions is any less helpful than doing the same without the being nice part.

Comment: "English is not their first language so the unambiguous compiler message is extra complicated for them": the language of SO is English. Do we really lower the quality bar just because someone *might* not have English as their first language?

Comment: @MartinJames: If you genuinely can't reply without being rude, just don't reply at all. Downvote, vote-to-close where appropriate, and *move on*.

Comment: @Raedwald: There's a difference between "lowering the quality bar" and "not being a jerk." Nobody is suggesting that we tolerate such questions, but being snippy about them isn't helping either.

Comment: I could indeed just down and close vote, and will probably do so in future so as to avoid getting suspended.  My next meta question will then be about being continually beaten up for not supplying reasons for commenting and downvoting :(

Comment: @MartinJames: "Beaten up" *by whom*? Downvoting is completely anonymous. Close votes aren't, but users can't ping you in comments just because you were 1 of 5 people to close vote.

Comment: @Raedwald I'm not advocating changing scope to accommodate non English speakers, I'm saying that your definition of reasonable is based on your own abilities, not theirs. With that in mind, it makes sense to be understanding and friendly towards people who might not have fluent English, even as you closevote/downvote.

Comment: Why do we give the asker the benefit of the doubt but not the commenter?

Comment: Help vampires vs those with stakes; only two sides there are ...

Comment: If I could vote this answer up 10 times, I would. This question reeks of elitism and 'I'm so much better than you, get off my board' type of attitude. Nobody should be rude here, especially to non-professionals who just want to learn

Comment: Blunt can be interpreted as rude, it is all so objective, and I agree people's feelings are important but also honesty is part of education. Students can't be running the class room.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson don't forget, pointy-end towards opponent:)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Comments are second class citizens, they're deleted or removed pretty liberally. Posts need to go through a more rigorous process. In addition to that I think it's worth giving low rep users more benefit of the doubt because they're somewhat new to the site and need time to learn it (even if their account age is quite high).

Comment: @ShaneC 'tardy' is not an insult in the UK, it just means 'late', or 'delayed', which it why I used it in the context of a 15-month gap.  Also, 'incompetent' is not an insult amongst those who are not expected to be competent.  I am an incompetent billionaire stock dealer:(    It's not an unreasonable term to use if someone cannot handle arguments/parameters in C, despite explicit compiler assistance.

Comment: Lazy and entitled is more rude than the blunt truth.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan On the other hand, the commenter has provably been helpful to many people in his time on the site, contributing useful content that has brought the asker and others here. The one is perhaps excusably ignorant, the other should maybe know better: seems about even to me.

Answer (score 83):

> It is beyond any doubt that the poster of this question is not competent to write C programs, (yet). Despite being a member of SO for 1 year, 3 months, s/he does not understand parameters/arguments and so cannot handle the clear and unabiguous, (for a change:), compiler error messages.
>
> So, obviously not a professional or enthusiast, and so is misusing SO
>   as a fixer for very basic errors that the most tardy of enthusiasts
>   would have sorted out after a week of learning, never mind 15 months.
>
> Is it really so unconstructive, offensive or hostile to point this
>   out?

In the manner you just pointed it out?

Yes. It is unconstructive:  Your response, however good it felt, doesn't give the OP a way to correct their action; instead of focusing on the behavior (not understanding a 'simple' error message), you focus on the person, by ascribing these attributes to them:

- not competent
- misusing Stack Overflow
- Not an enthusiast

It's most certainly hostile.  I wouldn't expect anyone to react in a civil manner to those charges being leveled against them.  "It's true" isn't a defense against being uncivil towards another person.

And finally, it is offensive; not only to the person on the receiving end, but to anyone who wants outsiders to believe that we're a welcoming crowd.  Every comment leveled like those above re-inforces the incorrect view that we're unwelcoming.

> I ask because my comment to that effect got deleted, and deleted comments tend to lead to account suspensions.

Only insofar as the reason they were deleted was because they were openly hostile towards others, or offensive, or rude.  "Too chatty" comments being deleted would not lead to a suspension, nor would "obsolete" comments.

> What is the recommended approach to such questions these days? 'Economy with the truth'? Pointless platitudes in an attempt to increase SO membership/revenue at the expense of Q&A quality? Ignore so that they can ask another question when they reach the next page of K&R?

Focus on the *question*, not on the person.  Don't ascribe attributes to a person; focus on the question.  We have a set criteria for why we close questions, "It's too easy", or "It's not worthy of being asked on Stack Overflow" are not reasons to close a question.

> I ask because my comment to that effect got deleted, and deleted comments tend to lead to account suspensions. Last time I moaned about 'i++ + ++i'-style UB questions, (ie. multi-duped garbage/trash from profs/TAs and copypasta straight to SO), I got suspended for 30 days.

[We've pointed out to you what sorts of comments will get you in trouble](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315122/16587); I'm not going to publish those conversations unless there becomes a reason to, but you have been told in the past what comments cross the line.

In this case, it was this particular comment that was deleted:

> 'Member for 1 year, 3 months' and you ask this? You are clearly not a professional or enthusiast programmer. You need to accumulate more knowlege and experience before posting here. ATM, you don't understand compiler error messages, even when they are explicit and clear, (and you are lucky that's the case - it's surely not always the case). – Martin James 7 hours ago

Comment: Just to be clear on the boundary between "constructive" and "offensive" -- would the very same comment without the first two sentences be acceptable?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No; partly because none of comment is actionable.  The comment focuses on what the user doesn't know; not how the user can fix the question or their understanding.

Comment: Duly noted. However, as we discussed under Martin Bonner's answer, advice of the form "you should read book XXX to hone up your skills" can very well be considered as hostile too. Could the best solution be not to comment at all in this situation?

Comment: "You should read a book" isnt' constructive; saying, "This `<specific resource>` talks about `<item they're having trouble with>`, on `<specific page or at this specific link>`.

Comment: "You should read a book" probably isn't constructive.  "You seem to be having difficulty with some of the fundamentals of the language; you would probably be better served by reading one of the appropriate books from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list rather than trying to teach yourself the language by asking questions on SO" does seem constructive to me.  Do others disagree?

Comment: @MartinBonner Still not really actionable.  Asking someone to read a list of books is vague; showing someone where their answer specifically is and the exact terminology in play is actionable.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: If the only thing to be acted on is *just* the specific question and nothing else, sure, Bonner's last suggested comment isn't that useful. Otherwise, the most constructive thing to do might be nudging someone who needs it to finally read a basic tutorial, be it in a book or not.

Comment: @Deduplicator Agreed. If a person is trying to become a programmer by having other people point out fragments of documentation to get them over each tiny hurdle, telling them that they need to read at least one book *all the way through* to acquire basic competence may hurt their feelings, but it's the best advice possible.

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting that in a question like the one this question is about, so to rephrase, _"How do I call a method with arguments in C"_, one cannot comment _"You're missing fundamental knowledge, go read a C book"_, but that we must link to a specific chapter in a specific book that explains that?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker "kill yourself" is certainly actionable, so it would be an acceptable comment? </sarcasm> But seriously, your whole reasoning is yet another example of shifting more of the burden of dealing with crappy questions (and by extension, users who ask them) onto the community, while also weakening the tools (close reasons) for the community to deal with them for the sake of being as "welcoming" as possible. Well, it might be more welcoming to leeches but it's certainly not welcoming to me or many other experts - I personally stopped contributing due to it.

Comment: @l4mpi The close reasons haven't been weakened. If anything we've added more over the years.  Initially there were only 5 when I started, with no "other" reason.

Comment: @George remember the "minimal understanding" close reason? Quite a lot of people were very upset that it was removed. Not to start that debate again, but it was the single best close reason for crap like OPs example. Anyways, that's only one of multiple things that increase the burden for users to attempt to moderate the site. Another example are the new profiles, [making it harder to check a users recent actions on the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290367/1110381). Or triage workflow being balanced against closing. I could go on, but I'd rather do something more productive...

Comment: @l4mpi We had an entire meta post over its removal. You could always start a new meta post to bring it back. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back

Comment: @GeorgeStocker nah, the debate last time made it pretty clear that SE (!= SO users) does not want such a close reason. I'd rather not waste my time, I'll just wait until the problem solves itself (meaning either SO finds a way to filter the crap, or another site will pop up to replace it). And again, it's not a singular thing such as that specific close reason. There are many small changes that show SE is shifting its focus. Things like "#SOReadyToHelp" which disregard the earlier community mantra that we don't exist to serve personalized help, but are a high quality knowledge repo.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker just to illustrate my point, the post you link to currently has a score >600; the highest scoring answers, both in favour of re-adding such a close reason, have scores >200 and ~350. SEs reaction was to add an answer explaining why they won't add such a close reason, which is the highest scoring answer agains those close reasons with a score barely over 80. So I don't see what could possibly be gained by attempting to start that debate again, except for yet another post by an SE employee explaining why they won't change the close reasons.

Answer (score 56):

It goes like this:

- You encounter a complete crap question, like the one linked, and you can rather quickly dismiss it as crap.
- Down vote.
- If you can't summon the energy to ***politely*** explain to the OP why the question is crap, then don't.
- Close vote if applicable. If you can't summon the energy to for example find a good duplicate, then don't.
- After the above steps, let the post be. It will eventually get dealt with in some way.

It is really as simple as that. Getting worked up and aggressive over a piece of meaningless internet spam is not worth it.

Furthermore, posting rude comments and insults is unacceptable behavior. It is something *much worse* than posting a crap question and not welcome on this site.

Comment: We seem to differ on the definition of 'rude' but, of course, I accept SE's definition of it on a SE site.

Comment: If you can point out where I have been insulting, I will apologize to whomever...

Comment: @MartinJames: It's kinda hard to do that when the comment in question was removed. All we have is your *description* of what that comment contained.

Comment: I would be fine with a mod. dumping my comment, either wholly, or in part, for criticism etc.

Comment: That pretty much sums it up. A poor question will likely disappear soon enough and nobody gets hurt, but negative emotions don't disappear as easily.

Answer (score 34):

Honesty without compassion tends to look a lot like brutality. That's not to say that some folks shouldn't take a *brutally honest* look at the way they've been going about things to improve their situation, but it's unlikely that they'll internalize it in the form of advice from strangers on the Internet.

I can see how one might be **honestly** trying to help by saying *you don't belong here, yet*, but it's very difficult to say that without just .. well .. saying that. It's simply not something people receive very well, they never hear or parse the *"yet"* and wonder why that might be.

Our software gives folks a few chances to get it right; to figure out why they're not being very well-received, and encourage them to put some more thought into their endeavors. But it's not a person telling them this, [it's the system itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243460/rolling-question-rate-limits-are-now-network-wide).

Yeah, this user has been around for a while, but has only asked *two questions*. But if the next one doesn't go over better - they'll have some more time to think about why not before they can ask again - along with all of the guidance that we've put together to help them.

Let the system do it's job - so you don't have to put yourself in awkward and uncomfortable situations. It's okay to point out "*I think you skipped a few steps early on...*" - but you gotta tell them what they were if you don't want to sound insulting. *You should only do that if you want to, and it makes you feel good*.

If not, well - they get their fair chances<sup>1</sup> to get it right like anyone else, and if they blow it, it's up to them to fix it.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Two questions in 15 months is a really odd edge case, which could cause stuff to fall out of the scope of the rolling blocks. But, the most they're doing is asking one belly-flop question per year, so ... if that picked up, they'd kick in.</sub>

Answer (score 17):

You make several claims here, both implicit and explicit:

- Honesty is being penalized
- The poster of that question is not a competent C programmer
- People who ask basic question on SO are neither professional nor enthusiast programmers, and are thus misusing the site
- There is nothing unconstructive, offensive or hostile in pointing this out

Honesty is only incurring a consequential penalty - your comment wasn't removed *because* it was honest. Honesty was simply present in a comment that happened to get removed. There are many honest comments that don't get removed.

I agree that the poster of that question doesn't look like a competent programmer - neither in C nor in any language that uses functions. While I would certainly rather they read some basic tutorials, or Google SO for similar questions, it didn't happen in this case. You've been here for over four years, so I suppose you've noticed that this is ***extremely common*** on SO. Competency doesn't really seem to matter in the slightest.

Do you think that professional or enthusiast programmers were born with knowledge of functions, pointers, stacks and queues, and recursion? Maybe that question's poster checked out SO last year, didn't see much he wanted to do, and has now returned in an effort to figure out some difficulties in a class or project he's started. Is he going to have a hard time? Of course. Is he misusing the site? I admit that I have a pretty broad definition of "enthusiast" (basically anyone who looks like they actually want to program, rather than some marketing weasel trying to get free labor), but that question seems solidly in that realm. And it's always possible that he somehow got hired as a developer and is lost to an extent that I can hardly conceive. If that's the case, don't worry; if he doesn't find a colleague to plagiarize from soon, he'll be out of a job.

Now for the easiest point: whether your comment matched a flag reason.

*What is constructive about such a comment?* It's the very definition of unconstructive. I can't see anything it might construct other than a sense of despair, and I don't think the writers of that flag reason had such a broad definition in mind. I guess such a comment is a little rude as well, but that flag is meant for the kind of words and phrases I'd rather not repeat.

If you want to be constructive, you can tell them that they'll have a much easier time with a tutorial, and provide a link to one. For example, I've posted several comments like the following:

> This is a fundamental part of writing maintainable Python programs. You'll have a much easier time with this if you check out the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html) first, particularly the section on defining functions.

If you think a question is unclear, not useful, or lacking in research effort, simply downvote it. If it's so unclear that you can't figure out what's being asked, or if it's too broad, not on-topic, etc., you can vote to close it. But if you leave a comment, make sure that it could at least potentially be read in a helpful tone. There's no way I could imagine a friendly or polite tone in something like "You've been a member for a year and you're asking questions that would be answered after a week of study? You are obviously incompetent, which means you're neither a professional nor enthusiast programmer, which means you're misusing this site." Compare that to a comment on that question that didn't get deleted as nonconstructive, as follows:

> "***too. few. arguments. in. function. call***"

which explains the error (albeit in a way that had already been proven useless, as the compiler already said that and it didn't help the asker). I can imagine someone standing next to the OP, pointing to the screen, and saying that in a stern voice, followed by looking expectantly at the OP and waiting for some sign of comprehension (a vain hope). It does sound like the poster is a bit irritated, of course, but they're still *trying to say something constructive*.

TL;DR: Honesty wasn't the reason your unconstructive comment got removed, nor could it prevent the removal.

Comment: The "I can imagine..." part made me laugh :)

Comment: You can be confident that, in future cases of a similar class, I will merely constructively repeat error messages in bold font in order to avoid censure:(

Comment: *"Compare that to a comment on that question that didn't get deleted as nonconstructive..."* Frankly, I'm surprised it didn't. It's not *rude* (though with the bold and full stops, it's certainly borderline), but it's definitely *not constructive*, given that the compiler already said that and the OP didn't understand it. When faced with the question "Why can't I walk through this door? It says the door isn't open.", the comment "Because the door isn't open." is not *constructive*. The comment "**because. the. door. isn't. open**" is at least borderline rude, from a random stranger on the net.

Comment: @T.J.: as hard as it may be to believe, I have in fact elicited some level of comprehension from questioners by simply reiterating an error message. E.g. "compiler says 'too few arguments', what's wrong?" then "well, you have too few arguments, just like the message says". Granted, I also pair that with a suggestion of what arguments might be worth passing. And I agree that adding bold face and periods doesn't help. But reiterating the error message can in fact be constructive.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Yeah, I think the key thing there is that it's *part* of an overall constructive comment. I do that too (carefully). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in the general case, reiteration of what the error message says may be useful to a novice because they may not have identified the key part of the error message amongst a lot of verbal noise (especially if, as is likely, they're using a language that spits out tracebacks on errors and have just encountered a traceback for the first time and have no idea how to read it) or because they've simply assumed that the error message is going to be some incomprehensible compilerspeak they can never comprehend and haven't even tried to understand it. In *this case* though, I agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see your comment, but from the wording used in your question, I'm guessing your comment was deleted because you wrote with a snobbish attitude, due to the user not knowing as much as you.

You think they're **'misusing SO'** and don't have a right to ask questions because you assume they're not professional programmers or even enthusiasts due to their basic understanding of code. Aside from that, using words like **'tardy'**, while claiming to be professional does not help anyone, least of all yourself.

I've experienced this type of attitude on other SE sites, and it does nothing to help novice users, or their knowledge on the subject. It shouldn't matter how bad the question is, constructive criticism is what these users need to improve, if you can't offer this kind of help, down-vote or leave the question be.

As other users have pointed out here, the [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy here for a reason, if it wasn't in place and people could say whatever they liked to new users then I would have given up on SO years ago when I was a fledgling unknowingly asking incomplete and frustratingly irrelevant questions

Comment: ^^^ it has another meaning?

Comment: Snobbish?  The questions was borderline insane, effective asking SO contributors to explain why 0 is not equal to 2 when the compiler has just emitted an error-message: '0 is not equal to 2'.   I don't have to be snobbish, elitist or any of the other adjectives commonly used by students when I, or someone else, refuses to do their entire homework for them in order to object to such questions, I just have to be rational.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Apologies then, tardy is a North American word. It's a juvenile slur everywhere else and not something you'd say in workplace outside of the US.

Comment: @MartinJames I can't see the original question, or your comment. But it's clear that you're defensive and passive aggressive even when not being attacked. You dislike the fact that everyone else doesn't agree with you. So much so, that you made your own question to voice your concern about being disagreed with. You have tools to deal with bad questions, downvote and point them to the guidelines, this is a Q&A site, not a roast.

Comment: I certainly did not mean to use 'tardy' in any other context than 'late'.  I had no knowledge, until now, that it could be perceived as an insult:(   It is not insulting or rude in the UK.

Comment: Ahhh.... ..Urban dictionary:  1) To express retardedness. 2) To express lateness.   All is revealed.   In this case, since I was highlighting the 15 months membership as a factor, it should be clear that I was referring to timing.

Comment: @MartinJames I've already apologised for my mistake, I never looked up Urban Dictionary for that definition, you did. I've only ever heard Americans say tardy, and that's only on TV. I've never once heard it in the UK or in Ireland or any European country, bar as a slur. This is an answer to your question that you're commenting, shouldn't you be attacking the logic of the question if you don't agree with it, instead of focusing on one word that I've already apologised for misunderstanding?

Comment: @MartinJames, you don't need to apologize for not knowing schoolyard insults in other countries.

Comment: @MartinJames - tardy means *late* in the US as well, Urban dictionary is just a bunch of kids making up shit most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I am a newbie so I'm sure I sometimes post questions that seem silly to more experienced users such as hobbyists who have spent years programming or software developers who program professionally.  However I'd like to point out that when I post my questions it's often because I sincerely don't know the answer and I hope that someone with more expertise than me on Stack Overflow has the ability and willingness to help me.  I only post questions when I have failed to find an answer through my own efforts (such as Googling and searching existing SO questions) which means even when my questions seem silly I am still genuinely looking for help.  When you share answers with newbies like me it is genuinely helpful even if you view the question as silly and I am grateful when you answer my questions.  Thanks everybody!

Comment: Whether an answer to your question would actually help you personally is not under disussion, though we certainly hope so. But even if it would, that doesn't make it an acceptable question for SO. Now, you also said you did some genuine research! Well, if that's true, and the question reflects that, it's quite likely to be a good question, even if it might be "basic".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the point of SO is to ask and answer questions, not to offer life/career advice. Ignore (or down-vote, or flag) questions that suck, don't get sucked in when you offer an answer and the OP clearly doesn't understand because they just don't know coding well enough. Offer something helpful if you wish, and move on.

Comment: Just ask and answer *any* questions, without any further aim? What defines whether a questions "sucks"?

Comment: In your personal view, of course. If the question doesn't interest _you_, ignore it

Comment: Yeah, granted. didn't work that well, did it.  Despite my efforts, misguided or otherwise, four rep-personalServicesPeople answered and all got exactly one upvote each, (before the question got closed).  That's just about what I expect, these days:(

Answer (score -2):

> So, obviously not a professional or enthusiast, and so is misusing SO
>   as a fixer for very basic errors that the most tardy of enthusiasts
>   would have sorted out after a week of learning, never mind 15 months.

- "misusing": Is it really misuse?
- "the most tardy": That feels hostile
- "never mind 15 months": That feels hostile too (they way have joined SO for one class that lasted a month, and now they are starting another one - just as an example).

> Is it really so unconstructive, offensive or hostile to point this out?

I think it is, yes.  Suggesting what they ought to do is constructive (for example, go and read a book from a recommended book list).  I don't see how what you have posted is.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't consider *Go read a book* as very constructive, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I've tried.  It's a bit hard to be specific because the question has been deleted.

Comment: Fair enough.  Can you agree it is *more* constructive than the OP's wording?

Comment: To be fair, the question was abysmal. Complete with caps everywhere and `KINDLY HELP!` at the end. I don't know exactly what Martin's comment was, but I'm not convinced your approach would have been met with better results.

Comment: Does all criticism sound hostile to you? Instead of focusing on the feelings you get from being criticised it's more productive to focus on making improvements based on the criticism.

Comment: @MartinBonner I wasn't talking about the downvotes; I was disagreeing with how you view the OP's behaviour.

Comment: @NewWorld: Ah right.  I misunderstood.  Not all criticism is hostile, I think the OPs wording in this post was.  It all feels aimed at the author of the questioner, rather than at the question.

Comment: I think "correct but not useful" is a reasonable description.