# What could Stack Exchange Inc do to make moderators who've recently resigned want to stay?

Tags: discussion, moderators, stack-exchange

*To the moderators who've recently decided (or been forced) to resign their positions...*

### What could Stack Exchange Inc do to change your mind?

Clearly you don't expect the company is capable or willing to change, else you'd not be resigning. Most of you have done a fine job of articulating your reasons for leaving.  You have widespread support among your fellow moderators and contributors to SO.  We all thank you for all you've done to help build the fine resource that is Stack Overflow.

I'd like to provide a place where you may, should you feel so inclined, provide a final, ***concrete set of specific actions*** that, if taken by management, would lead you to want to continue your great work here.

Comment: Revealing the company's goal could be convincing.  This is ultimately a dispute over who is in control over the sites' governance, the users and moderators that are present every day and know what works or a company that owns web servers and whose employees never involve themselves.  Seeing the most influential people quitting their contribution serves the company quite well, so no motivation at all to reveal anything.

Comment: We need a whistle-blower.  Not unthinkable, if I guess at the goal correctly then there are several employees whose prospects will be limited.  Not so sure they know however.

Comment: @kjhughes thank you so much for asking this. I don't blame the mods who have left. I also think it serves us well to do everything we can to save the ship.

Comment: @jinglesthula without answer to "what SO is now (Step 1 in George's answer)" it is hard to know what is actually being saved... So far it is getting more toward hosting secret "p@rn" folder/BBS on company site which urban legends say to happen sometimes to some companies in dark ages... maybe a bit more beneficial for Stack Exchange as they can collect clicks officially...

Comment: I assume you realize that there is an *inherent conflict* between the goals of the for-profit company and the goals of the unpaid volunteers. It's worth keeping that in mind when thinking about this question, especially when it's clear the company is trying to dramatically increase the profit from SO/SE. I suppose I'm just asking for some realism on the part of all. An answer that can be paraphrased as "just keep the servers running and leave the rest to us volunteers" is not useful.

Comment: @JamesKPolk can you please clarify what exactly is that "inherent conflict", especially currently? For long time the goal (at least stated one) was "let's produce a lot of high quality content so everyone visits our site" and I don't see how there is huge conflict you claim...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Perhaps I'm wrong, I'm no business expert. When I put myself in the shoes of someone trying to maximize revenue for stackoverflow, I find myself prioritizing things very differently. Let me give a non-answer by turning it around: if there were no conflict then my strawman "just keep the servers running and leave the rest to us volunteers" would be an excellent solution for everyone.

Comment: This present mess is a nice gift for the new CEO.  No, really.  It may not look that way, but consider: Pretty much _anything_ he does will be better as long as it's different from the current situation.

Comment: @HansPassant "Revealing the company's goal could be convincing." The goal could change any day. There is no guarantee that it stays the same or that it's not a lie. How could that be convincing? Let's face it: trust is a bit like belief. You never really know what happens in the future.

Comment: Well, doubling their pay will probably not work:)

Comment: They could start by being honest about any situation wherein people consider them to be at fault. Communication and honesty is the key to any relationship.

Comment: @Hans: Breathtakingly terse and to the point, as usual.

Comment: While a great prompt that will promote useful discussion, my experience in having left a company (followed suit by others) is that 1) the question needs to come from management, 2) they must propose actions first, and 3) this needed to happen sooner. Asking after someone leaves or even right before the breaking point is too late. *Emotions are at a high and trust is at an all time low.* That leads to discussions and negotiations that hurt in the long run. Coming back after such negotiations leaves a poor aftertaste and ultimately falls apart in the long term.

Comment: Rather than asking what can be changed for mods to *immediately* come back, it's better if long term solutions like what @GeorgeStocker posts is taken into consideration and the community is nurtured back into a positive state. Management needs to own the responsibility of earning back enough trust that these mods feel safe in committing their future to this platform once again. Keep the door open for them and let time & actions be the ultimate driver to bringing mods back to the platform in the future.

Comment: And to highlight one key point, #2, this is important because it shows that management sees this as a critically important issue, that they have listened *and* introspected about the causes, and are willing to be the one to offer an olive branch first. If the drive for change, at this point, comes from the mods who left, then it will never feel like both parties came to a peaceful, two-way understanding. Just my 2 cents having seen this play out before.

Comment: We need @HansPassant to take over as CEO. No, I'm not trolling.

Comment: The only correct answer is for SE to stop dictating and start listening and showing they value invested users again, and their actions so far have made it quite clear that they aren't interested in doing that. So unless they collectively pulls their thumbs out, there is nothing we as users can do, and no amount of "what if" questions are going to change that.

Comment: Nothing. The damage is done. The network is in a death spiral.

Comment: @RyanLundy The little conspiracy theorist sitting on my shoulder is whispering in my ear that all "this" has been engineered by the CEO so he could swoop in and save the day. (In 6-8 somethings...)

Comment: @SamuelLiew Why was this featured now?

Comment: @jpmc26 presumably because Yvette posted an answer asking why she wasn't reinstated yet.

Comment: Collate your own! This reads like "You told us, but could you just rewrite it in this format for our new internal systems".

Answer (score 405):

#### Step 1: Start With Why

Let me say first off that the community itself has done an extraordinary job surviving these... entanglements. It is a testament to how much people care that they're still coming here, day after day, to answer questions, edit questions, vote to close, vote to reopen, and flag posts for attention.  That isn't dedication that can be bought or sold; it comes from believing in a vision and continually executing towards that vision.

The original vision of Stack Overflow was a community where programmers could come together to share knowledge, and in that process of asking questions and getting answers, could create a repository of complete programming knowledge.

If I had to put it in 'vision-y' terms, I'd say the original vision was to put the best knowledge of programming topics at everyone's fingertips. Or, to make that vision more generic: To foster a community dedicated to putting their knowledge at all people's fingertips.

If you asked me what the "Why" ([Simon Sinek: "How great leaders inspire action"](https://www.ted.com/talks/simon_sinek_how_great_leaders_inspire_action?language=en)) behind Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange is, that's it.

That why is critically important -- it's perhaps the most important piece of the puzzle.  Understanding the new "why" allows us to decide if we buy-in to that, and if so to start executing towards it.  It also allows people who don't agree with that vision to self-select out of it, which is also critically important.  You want people to be a part of a community whose purpose they believe in.

Stack Overflow needs to figure out the "why" behind their Public Q&A. Why should people care? Why should they contribute? Why does it exist?

#### Step 2: Listen

(Whether you do step 2 first or second doesn't really matter; for our purposes you could even do them simultaneously).

Stack Overflow needs to learn how to listen again. The people here love Stack Overflow and are willing to dedicate their free time to making it better.  Some people here have spent 11 years dedicating their free time helping any way they can.  Can you imagine spending 11 years of your life doing any one thing?  Probably not.  And yet, it's happened here, for hundreds if not thousands of people.  In my case, I've been helping Stack Overflow for as long as I've known my wife, and nearly as long as I've been programming in the private sector.  These people who have dedicated their time have done so because they believe this is a relationship.  This isn't a transaction -- this experience of devoting time to Stack Overflow is as serious to them as investing in any other relationship they have.

One of the most important components of a relationship is listening.  Not to talk, not to respond, but to listen. To let that person you're in a relationship with tell you everything they feel they need to, and then to ask probing questions to understand more.  Agreement isn't the goal, understanding is.

Stack Overflow has forgotten that.  They forgot how to listen and forgot how to have a relationship with their community.  So the next step is to listen.  Whoever is the person in charge, their job is to seek out every meta thread they can, and listen. Be present. Respond by asking clarifying questions, or questions out of curiosity.  Seek to understand the world as those that spend their time dedicated to making Stack Overflow better.  There are two really important parts: The listener needs to be the person in charge of making the decisions; and they need to spend as long as needed to be able to say "I'm listening" and have it be believed.  Funny enough, Jeff called me once on the phone and we talked for 45 minutes.  It doesn't scale, obviously, but that's the level of listening we're talking about here.

#### Step 3: Patch up the holes

Once you've listened and once you've figured out your "why", the next step is to patch up the holes caused by the last few months (really since 2014, but first things first).  Even if you believe that this community is not salvageable, and you'd be better off not engaging, there are two issues with that point of view.

1. Everyone's watching, and they'll see how you treat people you dislike, and decide they don't want to ever fall into that category so it's easier not to volunteer, and
2. you're going to need some of the people because they're your power users, and they aren't easily replaced. You're talking years to replace the work and effort the power users put out.

Include these power users; schedule conferences with them; send them drafts, ask them how they feel about your "why".  Some of these could be moderators, but they don't have to be -- you're looking for the leaders in the community.  If you haven't found them after Step #2, then you've probably not been paying enough attention.

Your goal is to find the common ground with them, and to relentlessly maximize that common ground. -- It's not to change how they think; it's to see the overlap in worldviews and use that as a means of diplomacy.

#### Step 4: Re-establish trust

You've got some pretty big holes to fill.  There are 170 communities, 600 moderators, and 3 CMs.  Your biggest step at this point is to re-establish the trust, and you do that by showing that you've listened and that their concerns are your concerns.  Bring your spirit of collaboration, and be vulnerable.  Don't hide the problems, speak of them openly.  Speak of your financial issues that cause you to be concerned about the health of the site.  Speak about the uncertainty. Embrace it.  You don't have to have the answers. We can help.

#### Step 5: Collaborate with the whole community at ideation.

Coming up with solutions and sharing them with us is a recipe for disaster, as you've seen.  You have a community full of problem solvers.  Bring us the problem. "Our numbers are falling, and that puts a downward strain on the viability of Q&A.  We have some ideas on how to fix that, but what are the problems that are causing that from your perspective?"

It costs you nothing to collaborate with us -- nothing forces you to use our answer, and the interchange of ideas ensures your community feels heard.

Finally, trust and re-empower your community managers to speak on behalf of the company. At some point, allowable communication from the company became centralized and de-humanized, to the detriment of all involved.  Bring back the human part. Empower your CMs to make and drive community building and community decisions. They're on the front lines, they've invested years into establishing trust with the community. Take advantage of that trust.

Comment: Wow, this is *really good advice.*

Comment: ^ seconded. It wasn't the lack of agreement with us that bothered me, but I couldn't put it exactly into words what it was that did. Thank you for articulating it so well George.

Comment: Brilliantly put George. Heck, even if they don't follow this advice in a "genuine we respect the community" point of view, then someone needs to understand that it *must* be done from a business point of view anyway (the two things are far less distinct than I think the powers that be *truly* realise (although pay lip service to))... If I were a potential investor I'd already be put-off, and if the bleeding continues, no one's going to want to use, let alone invest, in anything SO branded...

Comment: In that one "business insider" interview, the new CEO says that the "community is in the DNA". Maybe that is the problem, how on earth are they supposed to talk to their DNA? OK, seriously: thanks for keeping the constructive, positive attitude. But I can't help myself and wonder "how can you tell people to listen to you ... when they aren't listening to you".

Comment: ESR predicted how this "public Q&A platform" and "repository of complete programming knowledge" would slowly die by "hypercourtesy" back in 2001, before it even was born. Sad, but inevitable. However, if to discard community, then we still have the experience and the amassed body of knowledge. Even obsolete FAQs have much value, and this one yet have years ahead before becoming obsolete.

Comment: George, you have my vote for CEO of the company and to implement the 5-steps plan.

Comment: Somebody on staff at SO really needs to take this back to the company.  I love the anecdote about Jeff, that's the kind of thing that has been lost since his departure. I know Jeff's busy with Discourse, but maybe his intervention is required to help put SO back on course.

Comment: @DoctorJones Jeff hasn't been part of SE for several years now, I highly doubt he'd want to come back to help, nor would the SE exec be willing.

Comment: @DavidG, you see it all the time with [big companies when they've lost their way](https://www.thefiscaltimes.com/2015/10/05/Boomerang-CEOs-10-Founders-Who-Came-Back-Rescue-Their-Companies), what SO *wants* is irrelevant, it's what they *need* that matters. But yeah, I think Jeff is rightfully very happy with Discourse, there's nothing stopping him from having an advisory role at SO though whilst still working on Discourse.

Comment: @DoctorJones I think saying "all the time" is a little hyperbolic, but I do agree with the sentiment. However, what SE *want* is ultimately what will happen, we certainly haven't seen much in the way of strong enough leadership that would suggest that would ever go back to Jeff. I'm pretty sure they would view that as a huge failure and a step too far. (and yes, I realise they've already failed big)

Comment: Step 6: When launching new features or presenting new ideas, have the person ultimately responsible for that feature present it to the community. Instead of sending forth some poor cannon fodder dev or CM, who can't actually change anything or withdraw the bad idea.

Comment: I think, also, if the "why" has indeed changed and community members aren't with the new vision, that they be able to take their contributions with them. Otherwise it seems like a bait-and-switch. I donated my time to something specific, if this isn't it anymore, I want my contributions back. One of my biggest issues with this whole thing is the apparent attitude from SE that they got what they needed from us, so we as people are now superfluous to the new goal. If that's the case, let me take my value elsewhere, don't hold it hostage and brush me off.

Comment: I realize that view might be controversial, but really. If I donated to the Red Cross, then they changed their mission to something I find objectionable, I would never forgive Red Cross for duping me into supporting something I don't support. Give my donations back and let's part with no ill will.

Comment: @ChrisBaker I believe you can do that. I think the way it's licensed allows you to even create a full fork of SE elsewhere if you wanted to.

Comment: @divibisan You cannot take your contributions with you under the current paradigm. I have given an indefinite license to the site, and am not allowed to rescind that, even when they change the license without my consent.

Comment: @ChrisBaker I see, you were talking about removing it from SE too. Sorry, my mistake!

Comment: @ChrisBaker The taking back of your contributions is not possible, but you can take all the time and effort that you could have spent in the future here with you. That's at least something. If you want to part I would just part without ill will as it is.

Comment: @Trilarion it is possible, as in technically and conceptually possible. It is disallowed. There's a big difference. I like bait-and-switches even less than I like being discarded after years of work helping to build something here. 3 weeks ago I never thought like this or about this at all.

Comment: @ChrisBaker To be fair the bait-and-switch was completely open and you signed up for it when joining. You gave SO an indefinite license on your work. 3 weeks ago, if somebody had asked me if there was a chance of SO going down soon I would have said no way. Now I'm not so sure anymore.

Comment: @Trilarion Well, it's an open debate about the license thing, since I never authorized the license to be changed without my consent. But anyway, yeah, three weeks ago I would have reacted extremely negatively to the suggestion that I leave SO or stop contributing, because I thought the contributions and the contributors mattered. If a long-standing mod can't even get a fair shake, I have zero hope in having my own concerns addressed. I regret being naive enough to think this couldn't happen.

Comment: I thought about what the overall topic of all these five steps is and I think it's mostly a detailed plan for community-driven management. In all of these steps, the community is indeed the DNA (not only by lip service). Now, SO lost this focus in the last years and I wonder how much the old CEO and founder J.S. is actually kind of responsible for this. Did he kind of squander the future of SO by this? He will probably still be multi-millionaire so that's probably fine as a personal record, but maybe there could have been more.

Comment: As good as your recommendations are -- the critically necessary first step to regain trust is missing: **Restore Monica's privileges, immediately.** Her demotion was wrong in process and in fact and should be considered null and void. No process is needed to "reinstate" her; the demotion was never valid. That pebble set off this avalanche, and the avalanche won't stop as long as SE Inc. insists on perpetuating this mistake, no matter how much they try to fence it in.

Comment: I'm going to go against the stream and say these 5 steps completely miss the mark. You are talking about building a community, a relationship of trust, getting along and making SE a place of collaborate knowledge. That's not the goal. The goal is maximizing profit. Your steps take away from that profit. SE can go read-only and it probably won't hurt revenues, so all those moderators and experts leaving doesn't matter. Ads in front of people's eyes matter. The way to handle this is to hire someone to deal with the shit on meta and concentrate on the business. That's what you see happening.

Comment: The problem, @nwp, is that the community is the biggest resource the company has to profit off of.  Ads make money, yes, but it depends on the number of people that see them; there would be a notable decrease in ad revenue if they were to, e.g., go read-only.  Apart from that, a lot of the value given to the name "Stack Overflow, Inc." is in the combination of large knowledge base and vast community including many high-profile movers and shakers in the relevant worlds (e.g., a lot of the people on the C++ committee have SO accounts).  Damage to the community will understandably damage this.

Comment: Apart from that, a mass departure could easily turn into a business rival, if some of the power users that leave decide to start their own site.  While this wouldn't hurt at first, it could cause significant losses to the company in the long run (or fizzle out entirely, either way).

Answer (score 142):

1. Unconditionally reinstate Monica's moderator privileges, on all sites.
2. Keep political causes out of the SE platform.
3. Spend some time getting to know the communities, how they work, and the value that they provide.  SE has forgotten how their communities work and why they are so important.

Comment: #3 needs concrete actions, not just the lip service they've paid for the last 18 months.

Answer (score 87):

There's a number of problems that boil down to this one problem

## Actions are now being driven by fear instead of Community

I [posted this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334015/an-open-letter-on-the-state-of-curation-and-moderation) a few weeks back, while it was just starting to heat up

> People love this community. They want it to succeed, so much so they spend their own time and money (such as SoBotics and Charcoal) making sure it operates smoothly. The message being sent right now is that SO/SE really doesn't need curators or moderators. Even if you apologize right now, reinstate Monica, and convince the exodus of moderators to stop the damage may already be done. Those trusted curators may not ever come back, or even care enough to contribute. That was what Reddit missed. They tried to stem the anger over a poorly handled termination, when they had alienated the community at large and the firing was merely the catalyst.

Even if you take the least cynical view of the Monica situation, it's still hard not to see that Stack Overflow wants us to be afraid of the new rules, especially when a community manager [retweets things implying that if you disagree in the slightest, you have no place in SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335173/se-inc-director-of-public-qa-retweets-bad-faith-misrepresentative-tweet).

The purely cynical view here is that Monica was fired to drive home just how serious SO is about trans rights, and that we should take the new CoC seriously... or else. To date, SO continues to let the situation fester by saying Monica was [fired for violating the old CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology), but not *what specifically*. You have to feel bad for Cesar M, sent out to [die on the hill of explaining how the CoC isn't going to do to us what it did to Monica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes). There's now 17 sub-rules (and counting) to the [main rules](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/10/iterating-on-inclusion/).

All of this has replaced community. A place where we could try to belong, and if we hurt someone unintentionally, there was no fear of a banhammer falling on you. Whatever happened to [honest discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315092/why-is-being-honest-getting-penalized-these-days), where people who felt something was wrong could at least say so? ([not that Meta has ever been a kind place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256051/2370483)) I'm willing to bet, most of the moderators that have walked out (or those who would consider running) are not keen on being the bouncers for a poorly understood and implemented policy.

Until the time that [SO has our backs again](https://twitter.com/shog9/status/1184104301934731264), I don't see any improvement.

Comment: “especially when a community manager retweets ”. Actually it was Ms. Sara Chipps, "Director of Public Q&A"

Comment: "The purely cynical view here is that Monica was fired to drive home just how serious SO is about trans rights, and that we should take the new CoC seriously... or else." No, you can easily be more cynical than that. Example: SO is now dominated by ideological radicals that actually do not wish to tolerate differing beliefs on trans issues, even if you're willing to go quite a ways toward trying to peacefully coexist alongside people you strongly disagree with.

Answer (score 26):

I'd say it's gone a bit beyond anything they can do with words. They will have to show action, and it has to be something serious. I would expect nothing less than putting a mod at the board of directors table similar to how some companies might have a union rep there.

Anything that is less serious than that can be a sop to everyone just to make the current problems blow over, and once forgotten, start to implement changes that reduce the volunteer mods further - there's nothing a CEO likes less than the peasantry causing him a headache. So I, right now, expect SE will start to employ moderators instead and that'll be the end of "community involvement".

To ensure the community is fully involved means they have to be fully included in all the planning and policies going forward, I can't see much else being realistic now.

However, there's still the idea that the company is moving in a direction that is not compatible with the community. I can easily see questions being asked, and answered by employees of other companies (e.g. Microsoft currently uses GitHub for its documentation, there's no reason they can't start describing how-tos, samples, and documentation on SE instead). SE gets revenue, Microsoft gets information to all its developers, the community... is surplus to requirements.

Comment: Most constructive comment this relative newcomer has seen, so far, in this passionate debate: *"I would expect nothing less than putting a mod at the board of directors table similar to how some companies might have a union rep there."*

Comment: That's asking a lot of any mod.

Comment: @holdenweb I believe that company directors are usually compensated, enough so that a couple of directorships constitute an entire salary.

Comment: True, but that depends very much on the company and the services being performed for it. It also requires a rather different skill set, which without training few developers are going to possess. And if two directorships are required where do you imagine the other one is going to come from?

Comment: @holdenweb the people performing mod duties come from all walks of life, and SO isn't the only site in the family. A mod from politics or the workplace might already be a non-exec!

Comment: That would be little better than emplying moderators, as such people would be wholly dependent on SE for their income. Surely that wouldn't be a healthy position, since they'd hardly be in a position to stand up against the company line.

Answer (score 21):

### Reinstating the moderators who have applied for reinstatement would be helpful.

They've denied at least two Stack Overflow moderators requests for reinstatement under the new moderator reinstatement process. This is a bit rough considering when they stepped down there wasn't such a process and at least one was expecting to have returned by now and told so by the community management team.

There's a lot of inconsistencies and betrayal here that makes it hard to trust the site.

One thing I would like to know, if moderators have no say in who is community elected, how can they veto a moderator from returning? This is based on personalities and not on the election. If the moderators can veto people on being reinstated, wouldn't it follow those same moderators may object to the person being elected in the first place, and so giving a small number of people power to decide who gets in only further erodes the democratic process. That's providing the site wants a democratic process or just the illusion there is one or maybe they do not want one at all.

I'd like some answers there.

But hey, I may end up being denied reinstatement again for posting this answer, as I predicted in [a previous meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393266/3956566), where the reasons I was given was for posting on meta (this was the only post), although I was then told I was allowed to post on meta.

I'll reiterate:

> Even writing this, I'm wondering, will this affect my chances of being reinstated as a moderator. It's really not a nice atmosphere.

Love us or hate us as moderators, your community elected moderators are now being prevented from returning at the hands of a few people, both from the community team and/or the moderator team. Is that what is good for the site?

Comment: Curious, I was unaware this happened. Guess transparency and community involvement were never part of the moderator reinstatement process.

Comment: I'd love to see you back and helping us with the flag queue.

Comment: I'm getting a strange impression that "This is not personal" is only a one-way street.

Comment: @ErikA I was reinstated on Pets as a moderator and not on Stack Overflow, the other moderator was not reinstated on any sites. I've reapplied again to be reinstated and will continue to do so until they reinstate me. It is unfair.

Comment: @Scratte in what way do you mean "this is not personal" - just unsure exactly which part of this you're referring to.

Comment: @Yvette Now I'm even more confused, since afaict there's nothing site-specific in the reinstatement process. Apparently SE did think you were fit to be a moderator else they wouldn't have reinstated you on Pets. I'd certainly like having you as a mod again, appreciated your different viewpoint on some of the meta issues and I think that's a great thing to have.

Comment: I wish I could up vote this million times. Moderators have been elected by community. The ones that stepped down did that as form of protest, not because they were at fault. They should be able to get their moderator privileges back, if they want to without going through any kind of reinstatement process.

Comment: In these times, when the site is lacking moderators, it feels like a very poor move to hold back on moderator reinstatement.

Comment: @Yvette Mistakes (if any) made by a community member seem to be a personal mistake with personal consequences. It doesn't seem to be so if the mistake is made by individuals that is.. well.. "not part of the community"?. Also, the reinstatement process seems very odd, since I assume votes to reinstate suddenly have a lot of weight, depending on the vote type itself. I get the impression there are veto-rights, which make just one vote decide the outcome. If this is the case, the process is now rigged and includes a warning to anyone who dare say "Stop! This is all wrong!".

Comment: @Scratte ah, thanks for the clarity. Yes, potentially one person, either an employee or moderator has veto rights. So, even without breaking the code of conduct, we can be vetoed. Insanity and feels like betrayal. It's hard work being elected as a mod and not everyone like every mod, but face it, a lot of people vote for those mods, so there's a reason they're elected. Not to mention I handled 75,000 flags and the thank you I get it, reapply again later. Well I have reapplied later and am waiting.

Comment: Thanks to all for your support. I won't reply individually to everyone.

Comment: *Now I'm even more confused, since afaict there's nothing site-specific in the reinstatement process.* @ErikA [The first note at the end of the process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336175/what-is-the-process-for-reinstating-a-moderator): *"...the outcomes for each site **can** be different given the first step in the Execution Phase..."* The first step of the Execution Phase is consultation with the current moderation team, hence Yvette's suspicion that it's at least one moderator preventing her from being reinstated.

Comment: @BSMP I'm not suspicious - it's a fact. I was told at least one moderator objected. And it was apparently due to my meta contributions, which at the time are well documented. There was the one post where I stated - it will probably affect my reinstatement and it did! I'm not allowed to have an opinion. It is an excuse anyway. These people don't want me back. But they probably didn't want me as a mod in the first place - so why should they decide now?

Comment: OK. The and/or part here, *"both from the community team and/or the moderator team"*, was what made it sound like you weren't sure. That you were told a moderator objected is useful information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/election/12

Comment: @S.S.Anne if we're eligible to run for moderator, we should be eligible to be reinstated

Comment: *shrug* . . . .

Comment: "if we're eligible to run for moderator, we should be eligible to be reinstated" YES. Except, you have already been elected. I know that there may be some animosity between mods and they don't have to be in agreement all the time. That can also be true for newly elected mods. This whole process does not make any sense at all.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I agree. I will keep applying to be reinstated until they reinstate me. If the mods could veto people from being mods, I'd never have been elected in the first place. So it makes sense I'm being vetoed out of being reinstated. It's really an unfair policy, particularly given the team (community and mod teams) knew I was coming back - it was announced to everyone and is detailed in emails.

Answer (score 12):

There may be discords but it surely takes two to tango.

My wish list;

1. Planning;

   Things should be more structured, measured and balanced. No rush and crush nor try and error. Decision (at all level) should be more and more data driven.
2. A clear separation of powers;

   Stack Exchange Inc may play the political or business role but should not forget about the origin and essence of the community. Moderators represent what we stand for and maintain the community. They should a (clearly defined) place in the decision making process rather than being dictated.
3. Effective communication;

   Silence is also a form of communication. It may be effective but not necessarily the best option at all time. Giving a response or feedback in a timely manner may be a great avenue to pave way for a healthy discourse, understanding and mutual respect. That goes in hand with a sense transparency and accountability, to foster trust.

Comment: "*Decision (at all level) should be more and more data driven.*" - But there is an important step first: doing a good job with statistics and data collection. There are some cases where they either biased the data or misinterpreted the results or even did both at the same time.

Comment: Not to mention that "data" isn't necessarily *right*. The "data" might well *support* the current event stream. Or the "data" might suggest that since the majority of users don't even *know* what's been going on that they don't *care* about what's going on.

Comment: `I can prove anything by statistics except the truth.` -- [George Canning](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/George_Canning)

Answer (score 5):

Hire someone who's a respected moderator who participates on Meta as a community manager. It's a way to get the expertise of how to manage the stack-exchange community into the community management team.

Comment: See [Require Participation in a Community Before Making Decisions that Affect That Community's Future](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387435)

Answer (score -37):

> I'd like to provide a place where you may, should you feel so
>   inclined, provide a final, concrete set of specific actions that, if
>   taken by management, would lead you to want to continue your great
>   work here.

Stack Overflow has no serious competition. As long as the company maintains its competitive advantage, the people who resigned will eventually come back. They don't have a choice. The new forum (sorry I forgot the name something like Cord...) couldn't possibly take off without very significant amount of investment. It's not going to happen.

It's like the China great firewall. The Chinese don't like it nor do they agree with the government policies, but they have no choice. People here will get used to it.

**PS:** The people who resigned including Monica herself still come to the site every day. Why come back if they hate the site?

Comment: They don't hate the site, they disagree with the policies which are destroying the very site in which they put in years of effort.

Comment: `the people who resigned will eventually come back. They don't have a choice.` But they do - they can just walk away and do something entirely different with the slices of time they had up until now donated to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Monica didn't resign.

Comment: The site you're not thinking of is https://codidact.org, I believe.

Comment: _It's like the China great firewall. The Chinese don't like it nor do they agree with the government policies, but they have no choice. People here will get used to it._ --> China is communist. Are we going to make SO like that? You shouldn't compare China with Stack, at all.