# Why are there only 2 moderator positions in the 2020 Moderator Election?

Tags: support, moderators, moderator-election

The [2020 Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12) page appears to have gone live recently and it shows that only 2 positions are available for new moderators (despite losing at least 5 moderators in the last year through [resignations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moderator-resignation?tab=Newest)).

In addition, it feels like custom moderator flags have been getting handled more slowly recently

Is there any reason why there are only 2 moderator positions to be filled when it feels (to users) like more are needed?

Comment: maybe they forgot the 0. It should be 20

Comment: Maybe it's because they <3 us so much.

Comment: There should at least be 7 positions (5 to catch up with the amount we lost,  another 2 to upscale capacity)

Comment: Kudos for the `support` tag!

Comment: Where does it *"have gone live recently"* exactly?

Comment: @Zoe: Jon Clements has been back a while. Not that 4 vs 5 is that big of a difference...

Comment: Yvette was asking for reinstatement as well, but I think her request was declined.

Comment: @yivi Yes, this was [confirmed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390493/what-could-stack-exchange-inc-do-to-make-moderators-whove-recently-resigned-wan/398030#398030)

Comment: @Sinatr https://stackoverflow.com/election/12

Comment: 7 positions all at once mean 7 new people to explain the stuff to, and possibly not filtering the candidates enough too. We're not that desperate. Sorry, GTG I've got 430 custom flags to handle.

Comment: Simply put, you can't make up for the loss all at once. 20 (or even 7) new moderators is just too many. Most of the time, we don't even have 20 candidates. This is just a regular election. Don't take it as any more than that.

Comment: @CodyGray And we're up to 4! mod responses on the post, will it go higher, find out next week on SO Modwatch (:p)

Comment: Nah, we'll just start appearing in Speedos, and you will be sorry. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray aw, spoil sport! I was looking forward to shocking the Meta nation with my speedo + ninja mask + hairy belly combo! Now they are warned :-(

Comment: @TylerH, and how am I supposed to find this page? If page exists, it doesn't means what it goes live imho, unless there are links to it. I was expecting an announcement, that would be official "going live". Since there is none, this page is something under construction, nobody should be there yet.

Comment: Another 'issue' is you only have 3 votes per election. Having 3 slots to fill or 20 slots to fill at the same election while still getting 3 votes per election *will* influence the value of each vote.

Comment: @Mast This is somewhat addressed by Cat's comment on the answer

Comment: @Sinatr Well, when the election actually starts, I'm sure an announcement will be made and other links will be activated. A moderator mentioned in chat that it was happening and they were allowed to mention it. That's probably where OP found out about it (and found the link).

Comment: @TylerH Pretty much, had been discussing when the next election would be in discord about 30min beforehand, then someone dropped in with the link and a note saying where it came from :)

Comment: I like some of you mods, and I feel bad for your workload. But this election I think I will abstain from voting.

Comment: @Michael-Where'sClayShirky that is unfortunate. Not knowing your exact motives nor wanting to hash that out here in comments but maybe your reasons can be worded as a question on the Election Meta Q/A with the goal to get some confidence back and/or get confirmation you have made the right decision. I feel purposely not voting is also a vote, those user should have a voice.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

New moderators bring in a fresh set of eyes to the flag queue, and new enthusiasm for helping out. They also bring in new questions, on boarding work and take time to get up to speed. Bringing in *more* new moderators makes that process a little bit harder.

I'm fairly certain that each new moderator makes a mistake and gets called out on meta for it (rightfully). This learning experience also takes a little bit of a toll. It is a learning opportunity, but takes time to resolve and communicate the *why* it happened.

Elections generally bring in two to three new moderators. This election is no different. It will allow us to refill some of our open positions, but also allow new moderators the time they need to learn the position and be effective at their new role. After they have reached that point, we can reevaluate if more of the positions need to be filled. There are ways to do that, by either calling up runners up from the previous election or holding another election in a few months. There is precedence for both paths.

For *this* election though, we're following the same sort of reasoning we usually do. Bring in new moderators, help them learn their new tools and the existing team. This will make everything smoother, even if it takes a bit longer to return to the numbers we were at, if those numbers are still needed.

Comment: If calling up the runners up is a strong possibility, is it possible to just have everyone vote for their top 5 in this election (instead of top 3)?

Comment: @BSMP Not currently. We've had some upgrades to the election in planning for a while and one of them is to allow people to rank all of the candidates (up to 10) rather than only the top three. I have an answer to this that addresses the reasoning for the 2 slots from that angle typed up but haven't posted it since Andy's answer is the actual reason and the technical limitations is true but not applicable since this reasoning trumps it.

Comment: @Catija Small request here to allow election voters to negatively/null rank people we think should definitely not be moderators even if there end up being 10 spots needed.

Comment: @TylerH Yep. The design would be the same as current... you *may* choose up to three but you can choose to only select 1... so if there are 10, you should only vote for the people you actually want to see as moderators. We've been talking about the wording to make sure people don't vote for people they think are poor candidates. I don't think we'd do negative votes - it adds a ton more complexity and we do have that during primaries - but we'll absolutely allow null votes.

Comment: I've also been toying with the idea of reducing the number of nominees that trigger a primary more adaptively... things like... if there's only one slot, 10 candidates is a bit much, so having a primary if there are more than five would let more people "downvote" candidates to get the top choices in the pool. There are a lot of knock-on effects there, though, so we have to be careful about that.... for example, even having a primary can reduce the number of voters because people have to vote twice.