# Why was my comment deleted from the election questionnaire thread of 2020?

Tags: discussion, meta, moderator-election, deleted-comments, specific-comment

Others disagreement comments are still there. Why is only mine deleted?

What was wrong with my comment?

[2020 Community Moderator Election - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399106/2020-community-moderator-election-questionnaire/399162?noredirect=1#comment781331_399162)

Comment: What was your comment?

Comment: It was one of the "i'd never support this candidate because <snip>" ones. there were several. That's... not what the Q&A is for, it's for asking further questions and/or clarification of the answers to the provided questions.

Comment: Though... you'll notice all the comments not doing that that were supportive of the candidate were left alone.

Comment: Comments on elections are strange things anyway. They don't really scale well, if there's back and forth you have 100 comments in no time with no way to distinguish important ones because of no votes. And if you're bringing criticism, you thread the very dangerous line of criticizing a person but not being allowed to say something unkind. I'd be all for purging them regularly, say every 24 hours.

Comment: @KevinB Flag them? Moderators don't see the entire comment thread when people flag comments unless they go out of their way to look at the original post. They just see what was flagged.

Comment: @KevinB Actually, I went to check my support comments (2) I left a few days ago, and they disappeared too.

Comment: Same thing happened to me and other critical voices in the comments. I find this censorship amidst an election appalling. It further undermines my belief in the moderators supporting Yvette.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For the purposes of complete transparency, your comment was the following:

> I had interacted under your post with someone else during Monica's problem. I remember how hostile your behaviour was towards me. I was very surprised to know at that time you were once a moderator. You were telling everyone to get on with their life and get out of Monica's issue. You weren't supportive of the community's revolt which finally helped to get Monica some justice. I would be disappointed if you are selected as a Moderator.

It was flagged as "harassment, bigotry, or abuse" by another community member. A moderator (not me) saw this flag and indulged it, choosing to delete the comment.

I do not agree with this deletion. First of all, I do not think the comment counts as "harassment, bigotry, or abuse". I do think that the comment would be utterly out of place on a normal post, but I don't think it is for an election nomination. Nominating yourself for moderator is a proactive choice to place yourself in the limelight and thus subject yourself to community review and criticism. For one thing, when elected, moderators have to take a whole lot worse. But that's not a good justification. The important justification is that the community puts an *extreme* amount of trust into diamond moderators, given the amount of power that diamond moderators have. It is therefore critical for the community to be able to vet their moderator candidates.

[Robert Harvey tries to claim that comments can be deleted at any time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399351). While that is the official line when it comes to comments on posts (one that I'm on record as disagreeing with in its pure flippancy), it doesn't make sense when applied to comments on nomination posts. As [I told Robert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399350/why-was-my-comment-deleted-from-this-election-thread#comment782118_399351):

> This philosophy doesn't work on election nominations, since there's no other way to meaningfully engage. In a [normal] Meta question [or a question on the main site], you could post your own answer. But unless you're nominating yourself, there's no other way to engage with the nominees.

In other words, the justification for this policy that comments are temporary/transient/ephemeral/whatever is that they are meant to be suggestions on how to improve the post. If you want something permanent, it should be posted as an answer. That is not applicable to nomination posts, where the only way to engage with a candidate, ask questions, or state your opinion regarding the candidate's suitability is to post a comment.

As such, I've undeleted your comment there.

Comment: Totally agree with the undeletion.  See?  This is exactly what I was talking about in my answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, I never said that *the policy* was that comments can be deleted at any time for any reason.  I said that *that is what happens in practice.*

Comment: Oh, so that's how my reply to Magisch in the nomination thread got undeleted? Thanks, Cody :)

Comment: çan you make it clear I did not flag the comment?

Comment: flagging this comment as abusive sounds like [MSE worst practices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336409/165773). Thank you _very much_ for stopping that

Comment: Thank you for taking the thread seriously, the detailed answer, and the undeletion. I was concerned because other comments criticising the candidate are still there. Only mine was deleted. I didn't consider that fair.

Comment: @Yvette Flags are strictly confidential. I intentionally did not give any indication about who might have flagged the comment, and I do not plan to give any more.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl Absolutely. I do take this kind of thing seriously, and I understand why you would be concerned. Aside from it being my natural inclination, the reason I spill a lot of words on this is that I recognize it *is* a delicate balance between being respectful to the candidates while also being able to make criticisms. Elections *need* to be given more latitude than we normally would because, unlike every other action on this site, elections actually *are* about people. As Frederic surmised, I've undeleted other comments on the nominations to avoid the illusion of favoritism.

Comment: @CodyGray you can say I didn't flag it, that does not give away who did flag it. I have no clue who flagged it. Given there is a comment under the nomination accusing me of flag bombing, that was deleted and undeleted, it's a fair request. No need to be punitive about it Cody, it's within the spirit of the law.

Comment: I'm happy to confirm you didn't flag the comment @Yvette

Comment: @JonClements thanks pup :)

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl: Actually, I was dead serious in my answer.

Comment: @robert ofcourse I know that. That's the generic answer given to such threads.

Answer (score 7):

Just assume that comments are temporary, that they will be deleted without warning for any reason or no reason at all, and you won't have any further problems using them.

Comment: That's certainly the general policy site-wide, but does it make sense for that to be the policy on an election questionnaire thread, where the explicit intention is to generate discussion in the comments? That seems like a case where the expectation needs to be different.

Comment: `...where the explicit intention is to generate discussion in the comments` -- You could make that same claim about any meta thread, not just elections.  I don't see elections as being materially different in that regard.  Nothing in the meta post suggests otherwise.

Comment: I guess that they're different to my eye in that they're a unique, officially-sanctioned event where only certain users (the nominees) are intended to leave answers rather than comments. But sure - the same question could be applied other places on Meta.

Comment: I don't really buy this as an answer. We all know comments are transient, but if we take that to mean "completely worthless, treat them like you never posted them in the first place, don't question it if they disappear at random" then there is literally no point in posting them in the first place and so the comments section should be removed.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: This has simply been my experience using comments. The rules aren't clear enough to be interpreted any other way, or if they are, they aren't interpreted in the same way by each moderator. You therefore cannot rely on comments with any degree of confidence.

Comment: This philosophy doesn't work on election nominations, since there's no other way to meaningfully engage. In a Meta question, you could post your own answer. But unless you're nominating yourself, there's no other way to engage with the nominees.

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm happy to be proven wrong.  Show me the policy that exempts election posts.

Comment: What "policy" do you want me to show you? I'm using common sense. I believe you're familiar with it.

Comment: Common sense utterly fails on comment moderation.  The most common metric I've seen for justifying the move of comments to chat?  "Too many comments."  And if you wanted comments to be treated differently in election posts, you should have said so in the post.

Comment: Yes, when the comments underneath a post become too numerous, it interferes with constructive discussion and suggests that the comments have moved from the purpose of comments (suggesting improvements to the post and/or asking for clarification) to engaging in a discussion, which is better suited in chat. I'm not really sure what that has to do with anything, though, as the comment in question wasn't moved to chat, either. What do you mean if *I* wanted? I didn't write the post, and even if I had, we don't typically include meta-discussion like that in posts. Common sense works for me.