# How to improve voter turnout on moderator elections?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Firstly, I would like to wish for Makyen and Machavity.

The **2020 Community Moderator Election** ended yesterday. We see 750,753 voters were eligible for this moderator election this year. But 32,225 Users voted on the election. This election 4.29% percentage of eligible users voted. However, 95.71% of users did not vote in the election.

How to improve this situation and increase the total number of votes/ voters in the next election?

Comment: I prefer to see a small number of well informed voters who really know how the site works and have seen the candidates in action, rather than having a lot of people who don't really care voting more or less randomly for people they don't know. Maybe we need more people who care, though...

Comment: Why do we need more voters? You're acting on the assumption that everyone would agree with you, but that's not necessarily true.

Comment: You're approaching this from the wrong end. As @ThierryLathuille points out, voting would increase if more people actually cared for the site as a whole. The percentage of users who voted is the symptom, not the problem.

Comment: I am really tempted to vote this as duplicate of [Can we have Hot Meta Posts (HMP) re-enabled now that SE has admitted that Meta actually represents the engaged user base?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396255/839601) Because this was the proven way to involve broader audience into matters of maintaining the site

Comment: 95.71% of the users did not vote in the election but how many of those users have been active in the last 30, 60, 90 days?  I am active daily on another community but my Stack Overflow profile has been active for 5 years.  **I specifically opted to not participate in the voting process for personal reasons.**

Comment: @SecurityHound - you are absoulutely right: much, much less are active, even if we count only by login, the 4.5% is doubled. If we count those who posted anything during the election process (or last month for that matter), the percentage of those who voted goes even higher. If we leave only those who posted something non-negatively received, not closed as duplicate, etc - I bet the numbers will go higher still (I haven't done the last query yet).

Comment: correction: my Stack Overflow account has been inactive for 5 years not active.

Answer (score 17):

It's worth keeping in mind that Stack Overflow is ~11 years old at this point, and that you're eligible to vote at 150 reputation.

150 reputation is not a large amount of reputation. It is fairly easy for someone to reach that number with *a single post*.

So keeping those two things in mind, there are a *lot* of users who are eligible to vote but may have left the site, or were never really users of the site (one post and gone), or simply aren't invested in the election.

And it's *fine* that people aren't invested in the election. Moderation (and thus the election) is skewed more towards the power users; the ones who are deeply involved in the workings of the site. A casual user who occasionally asks or answers a post doesn't necessarily care about an election because it has no relevance to them - and that's fine.

There's no need to worry about the percentage of people who voted.

Comment: `with a single post.` with a single **good** post. I think 15 upvotes for a newcomer is extremely rare, especially on a technical site.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Perhaps "fairly easy" is correct in the very broad sense of "fairly easy" being.. "quite difficult" for must users ;) Even for Mithical :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - you [will be surprized](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1267283/posts-with-15-or-more-total-score-posted-by-users-created-a-month-ago?offset=1&score=15&period=month). At least 3 by those registered last month, 113 last half a year. Also, since accept gives 15 reputation, you only really need 14 (with that many upvotes it should usually be accepted)

Answer (score 5):

We do need more people voting, that's how the democratic process works and ideally, we would see the turnout [around 60%](https://www.agora-parl.org/sites/default/files/voter-turnout-trends-around-the-world_0.pdf), **but**: moderator elections are not comparable to state-wide elections, no issues concerning citizen wellbeing are decided here. This 4.29%  were cast by those who consider themselves invested enough in the future of the website, and in that context, nearly 5% is a good result.

You also need to take into account the recent divide between SE Inc and the community, which contributed to the election being viewed as a pointless or even harmful endeavor by many. Just take a look at some of the phenomena that accompanied the election:

1. [5 out of 10 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399106/2020-community-moderator-election-questionnaire) in the latest questionnaire were about the recent turmoil
2. one question stated "why do you still want to run?" in plain text
3. we had a protest vote candidate who basically ran as an "against everyone" checkbox

Additionally, every piece of data should be interpreted. Being "eligible" to vote in the context of moderator elections means only "having 150 reputation points". [Out of those](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1266347/users-eligible-for-voting-in-the-election-who-accessed-site-and-posted-in-6-month?reputation=150&offset=14&posted=yes&period=day) eligible, only 185 477 users posted anything and accessed the website in the last 6 months. Of those, only 53 918 last month, and only 26 796 were active during the last two weeks.

If we count only those who just logged in, 478 545 in 6 months, 383 059 last month, 331 807 last 2 weeks, and only 303 880 last 10 days, so about 10% of eligible users who logged in at all, voted. Given the above stats, an even higher percentage of those who are actually active, voted.

So, while having better representation during votes is desirable, we do not need to increase turnover *just* to increase it. What we need are:

1. better onboarding process (not the one that paints SO as rainbow land to news only to have this view be shuttered the first time they ask a poorly researched, horribly formatted and asked-to-death question without an MRE)
2. better experience for *established* users (on that note, we [finally got](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351118/improved-experience-for-users-with-review-suspensions?cb=1) review suspension notifications feature, which is a step in the right direction):

   - better *answering* experience (why does one have to add `resize: both` in dev tools to be able to increase answer box width? Can we [rediscuss using tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables?answertab=active#tab-top) in markdown?),
   - better *voting* experience (why does one have to spend a *non-refundable* point to downvote an answer?)
   - better *tagging* experience (why do we have to bother moderators, whose job is being arbiters, not concept cartographers, each time we need to merge anything?)

and much more, which requires a significant effort on both the community and company side. Until that is done, voting turnout is one of our least significant problems.

Comment: Suggesting that it was pointless or harmful sure demeans those who ran. Regardless of turmoil and politics the site still needs moderators to function. Personally I applaud those with the fortitude to run in face of all the turmoil

Comment: @charlietfl - I think you misread my intentions,I personally voted in it and consider the results a big success with Makyen and Machavity being appointed. The part about turmoil was pointing out to the OP the recent issues and public opinion that contributed to the election not being viewed as a positive phenomena (I watched this election closely including the surrounding discussion - many do indeed think that it is either pointless or harmfull )

Comment: Was referring to *"which contributed to the election being viewed as a pointless"* which makes it sound like that is your opinion. If it isn't you might suggest that  *"others may have that opinion"*

Comment: @charlietfl figured as much - bad wording then, maybe I do need a disclaimer :) Just wanted to clarify that I am actually a proponent of the elections and overall think that it is a shame we only had 2 mod positions this time available