# What explains the large number of people visiting the election page but not voting?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

I was reviewing the numbers on the last moderator election. According to the info blurb we had:

- 898,325 voters were eligible
- 313,847 visited the site during the election
- 73,995 visited the election page
- **21,764 voted**

Ignoring the overall 6-7% voting turnout, I wanted to focus on the path of the people who were part of the 74K election page visitors, but who did not vote (around 2/3).

I'm curious to why this might have been the case. Ideally, if you've gotten over the large hurdle of going to the election page in the first place I would have thought you would vote. That would be like arriving at a voting booth, reading the candidates and then... leaving?

- Perhaps they felt it difficult to differentiate the candidates?
- Perhaps they felt overwhelmed by the decision in the first place? I can imagine people reading the candidate blurbs, saying to themselves 'ah I'll do this later', then forgetting about it.
- Perhaps they missed the voting widget on the side? (Expected a form or buttons by
  the candidate?)
- Perhaps they were unsatisfied by all of the
  candidates?

Comment: Were all the visitors to the election page eligible to vote?

Comment: what exactly does "during the election" mean? during the election phase only? or also the nomination phase

Comment: IIRC, the stats only count eligible voters, because counting non-eligible voters is pretty stupid when they're statistically irrelevant

Comment: @cafce25 I'm making the assumption that those categories are subsets of one another. But thats a fair question.

Comment: @KevinB Only the election phase counts for that

Comment: My reading of it is each set of users is a subset of the previous number, but... I'm not comfortable just assuming the data being presented is the data I'd expect it to be, given... history

Comment: It is slightly lower than normal. 29% this time with the previous four being 34%, 38%, 33%, and 33%

Comment: For me, it was a hard thing, took a good amount of time. I also asked for help on election chat-room and got some feedback. Like myself, it is hard to sort the candidates where all are way better than me(beyond my acknowledgment). Maybe some others also feel the same way.

Comment: I guess that most of the people get a notification, open it and close it immediately because they are not interested

Comment: For me the third bullet almost applied. I dragged the candidates in the order I wanted, but realized only afterwards that I should drag them to the separate area and put them in the right order there.

Comment: Are you sure they are "real" visits? I'm dealing with link previews coming from things like Slack and Outlook, which I'd say aren't real visits but would show up in the stats.

Comment: In my case I had some userscript that removes box on the right with "The Overflow Blog", "Featured", and "Hot Meta Posts" links. This usersrcipt also remove the voting controls on the voting page, leaving me confused for a while.

Comment: "the large hurdle of going to the election page". It really couldn't be easier to go to the page. You get a notification, you click it.

Comment: I think we need statistics not only on the conversion tunnel, but also on the time each voter spent on the voting page, this would explain the reason for the rejection.

Comment: Were the visits that were counted unique users or were people visiting the election page more then once? I visited the voting page several times.

Comment: When there is an election the banner appears, but initially there are no candidates, having dismissed the banner you need to remember to come back; and vote for a candidate that you feel is suitable, in order for the visits and voted counts to be more equal.

Comment: @kirogasa I stay on the page just long enough to clear my notification and get my [caucus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1973/caucus?userid=1108305) badge.  So less than a second, if I'm paying attention to my browser window.

Comment: Honest answer: I came to voting page thrice and left as I was actually searching for (important/urgent) work related answer at the moment... then I forgot.
I eventually voted because of greed to earn a badge.
Sometimes life gets in the way, and reading so much about 6-7 candidates in a rush and deciding for a vote is mentally taxing. Reading, digesting, comparing, and then being sure to cast a vote is something better done when voters are mentally free while visiting the site... which usually isn't the case because SO is mostly visited when they are stuck with work having deadlines (mostly!)

Comment: Even though I am interested in casting the vote, and even though I have gratitude to the community and want to give back, the timing of the voting, when the notification appears, and then making a decision after reading about 6-7 candidates somehow fails to fit together easily. NOTE: both my comments are my personal opinion only and will not be applicable to everyone. hope it help.

Comment: How does this ratio compare to the that of users visiting the Review Queues page vs users actually reviewing more than one post?

Comment: In my case I couldn't be bothered. I opened the page, skimmed it, got bored and closed it. FWIW I have voted in several previous elections but it takes a hell of a lot of time and effort and I really couldn't care less this time.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

#### Informed voting is hard, and uninformed voting isn't helpful

To cast an informed vote on the candidates, you'd have to read, at the very least, all 6 candidate statements of approximately 1000 characters each.  Ideally, you'd also read all the questionnaires, so there's another 60 answers there.  And you'd want to read the several dozen comments on the candidates in the nomination tab, if you found them...  And maybe you're also interested in how they've engaged on the site or on meta...

Having done all that*, I felt qualified to cast a vote.  But I understand why people who use the site a lot less than me didn't want to go through the effort of figuring out who to vote for.

---

* In my case, I was already familiar with some of the candidates through previous interactions on the site/chat/meta, so it wasn't totally necessary for some of my votes, but I did read them to figure out how to rank people I thought were similarly qualified.

Comment: Your added sentence nails it. I actually considered not voting this year because I have been very out of touch with Stack Overflow moderation and am not as familiar with the candidates anymore. Shifting from the "I've interacted with these people" mindset to the "I have to learn about all these candidates" mindset really changes the prospect of voting for them.

Comment: This is definitely true! I don't vote in these elections for the same reason that I don't vote in elections for my local council: I go to the page expecting to see a wild superficial difference between candidates and thus an easy choice, but when looking at the options everyone seems to have pretty much the same platform on the surface, and digging deep to detect the differences would be a LOT of research. As a more casual user it's hard to justify spending more time researching election candidates than I would actually using the site in general over a month or two.

Comment: I also want to add:  I just don't care enough to devote the time & energy to be an informed voter. I give enough of my time to stack overflow. So I figure the elections are better left to those people who do have an interest in spending the time to be informed.

Comment: You are reading my mind. Although I found the patience to read and vote, I realize that if I had been in a different mood, I would not have wanted to read the candidates' long "About Me" stories. I would settle for stories about each candidate of no more than three lines of text, it would help me rate my voting time as quick (less than two minutes according to GTD (Get Thing Done)). I think we need statistics not only on the conversion tunnel, but also on the time each voter spent on the voting page, this would explain the reason for the rejection.

Comment: Agreed.  I bailed the first time I went in and actually started voting.  It was "too hard" to easily compare people I had no knowledge of.  I thought a table of the all the candidates' key criteria would have been very helpful for a first time voter.  And @kirogasa suggestion of "three lines" seems like a good one. SO discourages waffley material so perhaps if an applicant cannot "nail it" in  a few lines then they are not suitable.

Comment: I would add that all the candidates seem to me to be good, willing and bona fide people, so I preferred not to cast a superficial vote by giving preference to a particular person by my superficial knowledge of their actions in the real life on the network.

Comment: I don't think this is the reason why. Do you seriously think everyone voting does this same amount of candidate background study in a real-world political election? Of course not... and yet people vote in those elections. In democracies doing poorly, the participation might be around 50% of eligible voters, so still much higher numbers there, with far more people doing far less research...

Comment: I think the main reason is because users simply doesn't care. It's not like this is some open-source, community-driven project for the benefit of mankind. If some private company, like lets say Google, asked me to vote for which candidates to hire as unpaid janitors at the facility where their free search engine service is located, I would be mildly interested in voting. What do I care? The vast majority of people aren't morbidly fascinated in the dirt and dust located in that Google facility, let alone in some unpaid janitor candidates. Most people just want to use the search engine.

Comment: *”…and yet people vote in those elections…”* @Lundin Those elections have candidates who have spent months on advertising beforehand so even people who haven’t done research have an idea of who those people are. There are also real world consequences to not voting that don’t exist on Stack Overflow. (You don’t have to worry about moderators ignoring your flags because you didn’t vote, for example.)

Comment: And with the calibre of candidates high, it meant, at least for me, coming back on multiple occasions to re-read the answers to the questions as well as the comments. Reflecting on what I knew of their interactions on SO/SO-Meta. It seems only fair considering how much time and effort moderators put in and candidates also.

Comment: @BSMP There has been a shortage of moderators for the past 3-4 years, so there are consequences.

Comment: @Lundin The shortage of moderators wasn’t caused by too few people voting in the elections, at least not on Stack Overflow. As far as I know, this site hasn’t had an election fail because no one voted. Also, I said there are real world consequences to not voting in a political campaign that don’t exist here, not that there aren’t any consequences here at all.

Comment: @BSMP No but there's been a shortage of qualified candidates, which might in turn reduce people's willingness to vote. For example, the only reason I voted personally last year was that one candidate posted plagiarised replies to the questionnaire and I didn't want them to get elected because of that. That was setting the bar too low, otherwise I don't really care. I still don't understand why anyone sane would run for moderator after the "firing moderators" incident. Big respect to all mods who resigned at that time, little respect to those who willingly want to be unpaid corporate slaves...

Comment: @Lundin So you don't have any respect for any current moderator, doing volunteer work handling flags for people like you?  If you want to know why we ran, you can refer to question 2 in [the 2020 election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399106/208273), or question 4 in [the 2021 election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13).

Comment: @RyanM Not any more than for any other user. Some like reviewing flags and close votes, some like posting technical Q&A. I'm posting lots of hopefully quality technical content here free of charge. How is that less volunteer work? Though I do it mostly for selfish reasons, either because I find some interesting question or when I'm just bored. Sometimes even when I'm just feeling helpful. ->

Comment: The difference is that moderators have key roles and without them the site would come to a halt. Imagine if all those mods have quit back in 2019 and none would have volunteered to be "strike breakers". Then the company had been forced to stop messing around. Maybe forced to reprioritise the CM layoffs etc. Now in retrospect we know that the plan all along was just to make the company look as profitable as possible so they could dump it on someone foolish enough to buy it. I remember shareholders posting at meta during the "firing moderators" incident even, they wanted to drop the hot potato.

Comment: Definitely this answer. I did read through everything and vote, but it's a significant time investment, with the current setup you can't meaningfully differentiate the candidates in a short period of time. Voting "yes or no" for individual policies would be much quicker, and may be what some users expect when going to the SO election page.

Comment: @Lundin I was not a moderator during any of that.  I'll say that if I thought the company were likely to have a second round of that, I don't think I'd have run.  My interactions with staff have been pretty consistently positive, there have been leadership changes since, and they've shown a willingness to invest in tooling for moderators as well as the Community team itself.

Comment: @RyanM Except it wasn't the first round, more like the final round in a long series of very poor decisions. But indeed the leadership has changed since then, from actively harmful to notably absent...

Comment: @Patronics "Definitely this answer.  I did read through..." But maybe nobody else did read or only 30% did read and the others backed out immediately. A statistics about the time on page would be helpful to clarify it.

Comment: @RyanM "...shown a willingness to invest in tooling for moderators as well as the Community team itself..." Has the willingness already caused existing investment in tooling? I mean has the tooling really substantially improved, or is it still at the level of showing willingness?

Comment: @Trilarion the most visible improvement so far is in Community team staffing. Escalations are typically resolved within days, whereas not long ago it'd often take months. There have been tooling improvements but most of the ones rolled out so far have been pretty minor.

Answer (score 65):

When I get a notification about an election, I click on the notification to get it "resolved", but I don't have enough interest to actually vote for anyone.

I'm appreciative of those who do vote. Most of the time, I assume that, given the effort others have put into voting for good moderators, any problems in moderation are due to incorrect ideas rather than incorrect people, and therefore I mainly opine on moderation in meta rather than choose or reject moderators.

Error 404: [Democracy sausage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_sausage) not found.

Comment: Exactly the same reason for me. I just wanted that notification to go away. So I "visited" that page for a split second.

Comment: Surely the carrot of the "Constituent" badge is motivation enough to vote ;)

Comment: An honest answer, I can respect that.

Answer (score 47):

I would not consider myself dumb, and it took me 3 minutes to figure out where and how to vote. I was close to giving up.

The widget was super small, unintuitively placed (in my peripheral it looked like the normal "The Overflow Blog" widget), and my eyes were looking for a big button saying "VOTE" on every candidate's post. I even tried clicking stuff around the posts and visiting the candidates' profiles looking for the vote button.

Also I thought that you'd vote for one person, so the widget format did not instantly catch my attention as the place to vote.

Also when I had voted, I had no idea if it had actually registered or not, I refreshed the page trying to make sure the vote actually went through

Comment: Same here and I voted last year

Comment: And I thought that I was the only one...

Comment: The old system with "1st option", "2nd option", "3rd option" buttons next to each candidate was definitely more intuitive, but it had its drawbacks. Maybe if the current controls were put right in the middle of the blue "Election Phase" box...

Comment: Yes, it was missing a dismiss button (or at least some feedback that the votes were registered). It wasn't clear if the system actually would remember the voting.

Comment: @PeterMortensen There is open feature request https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371303/237989

Comment: i found the ranking system confusing too, i didnt expect to vote on every single appliquee. But in the end i agree the ranking process is probably better than voting for 1-2 people. Agreed that it shouldve been more obvious how to vote.

Answer (score 34):

Past years' experience has taught me that I get the [caucus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1973/caucus) badge for visiting the election page.  Since I get a free badge just by clicking a link and then immediately backing out, I always click through to it.

Comment: And you get another by voting [Constituent](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent)

Comment: @dippas Good to know.  Though I wouldn't be an [informed voter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421622/1108305).  And I don't feel like I'm meta-aware enough to get a sense of how my vote would affect the site, positively or negatively.

Answer (score 12):

I asked my friend did he vote, and he said

> I don't have time to read all that

He voted few years ago.

I read almost all on the first page and most comments. But the problem for me was that I don't know people. And I don't know how the ideal moderator should look (for me he should try to be kind most of the time and be active, but other than that I don't know). So if I want to make difference between the candidates I liked most, I needed more time to spend reviewing the activities of candidates, and I really don't want to do all this.

For me it is not just to read and vote, but to make a meaningful contribution. Obviously, I am not very active on SO meta to do this.

Few years ago I was just interested in how voting process looks on SO. These are two possible reasons for statistics in question.

Comment: Re *"he"*: That is an incorrect assumption (both [past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399106/2020-community-moderator-election-questionnaire/399162#399162) and present).

Comment: TL;DR is probably one of the main reasons people don't bother to vote.

Answer (score -17):

Perhaps they chose to abstain from voting due to dissatisfaction with how this site is being run by Stack Exchange Inc. (i.e. into the ground)?

Comment: I abstain from voting due to the general attitude I find in meta, exactly like this.

Comment: That kind of makes us wonder whether your reasons to continue interacting with folks on Meta encompass more than just the schadenfreude of seeing the platform slowly deteriorate.

Comment: Feel free to check how little interaction I have with people on meta. This comment brings the total up to 2? 3?

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger Given the poster's response to your comment, it sounds like he interacted with meta on this issue _because_ he actually cares about this issue enough to interact with and comment on it.

Comment: I decided not to visit the election page this year, because I don't think I know the site well enough to know what it needs to know who would be best suited to moderate.

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger I honestly don't know why I visit the site anymore. Habit, I suppose, to periodically clear the notifications. Occasionally I run across something that I feel would be worth spending a minute commenting on, like this. But this is pretty much it for me, although I'm not sure I even visited the election page. Doesn't mean I'm happy about what has happened to this community. Quite the opposite; it's very sad.

Comment: This is exactly why I haven't voted. I couldn't in good conscience contribute to putting someone in a monicable position.

Comment: @OmarL Nobody will be in that position again, for the foreseeable future. This _is_ something the company's learned from. Most of the people responsible for what happened to Monica don't even work there any more.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 maybe you're right, but I doubt it, and so do many others. And we don't have the energy to try and rebuild that trust.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The people changed, but I have never seen any indication the radical ideology was rooted out.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm not sure what you mean by "radical ideology". If you mean "be nice", that's always been part of Stack Overflow's ethos. If you mean "pre-emptively suspend people for questioning our plans to Ensure Niceness™" then… yeah, I'm pretty sure that's gone. Have you seen any indication it still exists?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I mean the one that required people in positions of authority to actively acquiesce to transgender ideology, irrespective of their own personal convictions, thereby making ideological uniformity a requirement. (Which incidentally was actually what happened with Monica: she was ousted not because she questioned the plans, but because questioning the plans meant she wasn't acquiescing to the ideology and wanted to ensure that people who don't are treated respectfully.) Has the mod agreement been rewritten to remove that? It never was as far as I know.

Comment: @jpmc26 Monica's objection was about _grammar_; that's the reason it was so ridiculous. As far as I'm aware, she's been nothing but supportive of her fellow moderators (unless you count kind and helpful). There _was_ an unhealthy environment being created for trans moderators, and if Monica had been involved in creating that, maybe her sacking would've been justified – but she wasn't.

Comment: Being hurtful, on the other hand, will never be okay. If that's your idea of an 'ideology', then I'm sorry, but Stack Overflow has had that ideology [from the very beginning](https://web.archive.org/web/20080916123307/http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: I feel obliged to note: Monica's view of the language – that singular 'they' is ungrammatical – isn't supported by etymological linguistic prescriptivism. 'They', singular, is attested in its modern sense in works written long before singular 'you' was in common use. (It had been understood for hundreds of years before Shakespeare used it) _But_, that's irrelevant; language is defined by how it's used. If someone's not comfortable speaking in a certain way, they **shouldn't** have some other "standard" version of the language forced on them. The whole situation was utter bullshit.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Monica's objection was only about grammar at a very surface level. The underlying issue was about refusing to categorize a person according to their preference and discussing what alternative approaches were acceptable. The staff's response was that no alternatives were acceptable, regardless of your personal convictions. Worse, they went on to insist you could not even abstain when it became an issue. That is blatant ideological discrimination, and [I am far from the only one to recognize it](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6718/22696). It was an intentional purge.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 As for "being hurtful," that was just another component of the radicalism.  [Staff members literally argued that giving factual warnings about filling up server disks was condescending](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7753744#7753744). Furthermore, no regard was given for the "hurt" caused to people with the opposite convictions, so concern for emotional pain is clearly not what any of those events were about. You don't hurl insults at people for trying to explain their beliefs if you actually care, much less twist their words to justify punishing them.

Comment: @jpmc26 With respect, you don't have access to the chat logs. Maybe there was some "underlying issue" like that I'm not aware of – but considering she's fine with neopronouns, I doubt it. If there's something she's written that makes you think otherwise, I'd be happy to read it, but never in my handful of interactions with Monica have I ever come away thinking "hey, she's kinda transphobic".

Comment: I'd like it if Stack Overflow could [redefine all our social rules to make them make more sense](https://xkcd.com/592/), but sadly, it can't. We have to work with how _other people_ communicate. So yeah, I'm very sympathetic to your point of view there, since I used to share it, but years of moderating online communities has taught me to disagree with you.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 "Transphobia" is a derogatory, dismissive label against people who stick to biological categories and reject performing chemical/surgical alterations as a solution to their internal feelings; it has long lost any useful meaning as a reference to actual hatred. Lots of people handle the push for normalizing it badly, sure, but no worse than people who embrace it handle the disagreement. That's a natural human reaction, regardless of position. The answer is to discourage poor responses on both sides, but SO has systematically and publicly shut down any dissent instead.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The link you're looking for can be found either by scrolling up or by following the reply arrow on the comment I linked. The comment you linked has nothing to do with rudeness; it's about whether a particular question is a good one or has problems due to lack of research. You have missed the context. The bit about the server-logs thing came later. I'd have to review the chat log to figure out exactly how we came to that point, but the discussion shifted by then (or possibly *because* of the extreme position Jon was taking).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249985/discussion-between-jpmc26-and-wizzwizz4).