# As an ordinary user on SO, what, if anything, can I do to campaign for my supported moderator candidate?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

As you can gather, I am a new contributor to Stack Overflow. However, in the relatively short period I have been here, I feel that I have identified one or more candidates in the current election that I feel exemplify the qualities that I want to see in an elected moderator.

1. Is it appropriate for me to exert any minor influence I have to improve the chances that my supported candidate(s) have in winning the election?
2. If so, what are appropriate ways that I can use my interaction with users on the site to support my candidate?

As an example, would it be appropriate to change my username to "Ian Supports [User] for Mod"? Would this have the desired effect, assuming my interactions with the community are positive and  I have the approval of the candidate? Are there other historical ways users have expressed their support?

Comment: I guess like any election in the real world, you can do this.

Comment: I mean, as long as you're not registering sock accounts to vote, illegally getting access to accounts, or otherwise violating the ToS or laws, it's mostly fine. Discussing candidates with people is also perfectly fine

Comment: A note, you can only change your username once every 30 days, so you'll be stuck with your endorsement for a while after the election ends in 9 days.

Comment: @Catija https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54986/566903

Comment: @pppery I'm aware. That doesn't mean it should be abused. The limit is there... working around it doesn't really make it OK. We have suspended people for misusing it (granted, there's usually something wrong with the username they choose, not just for general changing but...  it's still not really recommended).

Comment: Somewhat contra @Catija, I'm going to go out on a limb and say that (ab)using the feature to change your user name after an election is not real abuse, and that the moderator team (the existing one, not even allowing for the possibility that your campaigning worked to elect your top choice) would have no problems whatsoever with it. Frankly, I'd rather see the obsolete information *removed* from your user name than having it stick around for another 20+ days. Naturally, this doesn't disagree with Catija's more general point that if we find you abusing this feature otherwise, we will step in.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being called *Go Makyen Go Machavity* for 30 days ...

Comment: People express their support on the nomination page. "I believe you are the most eligible candidate in this election." as one example.

Comment: I think perhaps the thing that will help most for any candidate is having a dog as their avatar :D So if you can persuade them to do that, then you've done all you can ;)

Comment: Will you give us a report of what you did at the end of the election? :)

Answer (score 10):

I kind of feel like you're proving a point about mod elections, in that they're more a popularity contest than actually picking a good candidate to do this regrettably (mostly) thankless job.  To be fair, we've been blessed thus far that *most* of the elected mods have been actually good and competent moderators, but [correlation shouldn't imply causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation) here...

To answer your question directly, you as an individual can do very *little* to boost the profile of another person to be elected as a community moderator.  This is because of what I mentioned before - there is an indelible element of popularity when it comes to mod nominations.

Failing that - that is to say, if a candidate doesn't happen to be a household name on Meta or in a chat room or two - they have to hope that their responses to the questions are **rock solid**, or they're going to have a [snowball's chance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snowball%27s_chance_in_hell) of actually being elected by the community at large.

The best you can really do is encourage your champion to be more active in the community if they aren't already.  That'd be the best way to help them out, since without them being really known or understood, people aren't really going to be pulling for them.

Comment: Hey now! What do you mean "most"?

Comment: Oi! There is no need to call me out like that! @Cody, Makoto is being mean to me again 

Comment: @Martijn after [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398358/why-are-there-only-2-moderator-positions-in-the-2020-moderator-election#comment775898_398358) - it's understandable :p

Answer (score -7):

> If so, what are appropriate ways that I can use my interaction with users on the site to support my candidate?

In my eyes, the most **fair** *(maybe not the most effective)* way is to **state your support in your profile**. Unlike our posts, comments, etc., that belongs to the community, our profile is the one place where we can put our personal things without being accused of things like spam.

> As an example, would it be appropriate to change my username to "Ian Supports [User] for Mod"?

One can argue that our username is something we can write anything in. But, of all the users who vote *(tens of thousands)*, they *too* support a certain candidate. How does Stack OverFlow sound with all the users promoting a certain candidate on their username? We'd be divided into groups, and we don't want that.

---

Do some more contributions to the site (like answering questions), interact with users more often, heck, maybe change your profile picture into something more interesting, and eventually, more users will visit your profile to read what you have to say.

Again, it won't as effective as you'd want it to be, but just like in real life, to reach your goal, you *need* to work hard.

Comment: I think this will only have very limited impact. I'm not under the impression that profiles are read all that often.

Comment: @Scratte I know. But we need to work to legitimately get what we want.

Comment: I think changing ones username would have a wider audience :)

Comment: @Scratte Yes, it would.